# POST request in Sencha Touch

Tags: ajax, post, sencha-touch

HI, I am trying to make a POST request using Ajax in sencha touch.
my problem is when I am sending request my server accepts it as OPTIONS request. 
my code is :
var post_json = { usrname: username, password: password } ;

```
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            method: "POST",
            params: {
                user_session: post_json
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("sucessful");

            },
            failure: function(){                 
                alert("fail");
            }

        });
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you doing the request also from http://localhost:3000/? This might be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/jquery-why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-insted-of-a-get-request

Answer (score -3, accepted):

use JSONP insted of Ajax.request

Answer (score 1):

Add parameter:

```
useDefaultXhrHeader : false
```

If not, GET and POST method request will contain X-Requested-With header. I think this header is the reason why OPTIONS method request is sent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about CORS.This is my web.conf for asp.net:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

It worked in the IIS Server,but not OK in Asp.net Developer Server.