# jQuery posting JSON

Tags: jquery, json, post

update: I would like to pass the `var value` to the server

hello,
same old, same old ... :)

I have a form called `<form id="testForm" action="javascript:test()">` and a code area called `<code id="testArea"></code>`

I am using this code to stringify and display the data in the code area:

```
var formData = form2object('testForm');
document.getElementById('testArea').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(formData, null, '\t');
var value = JSON.stringify(formData, null, '\t');
```

What I want is to send this data to a JSON file.
I've been working on this project : http://ridegrab.com/profile_old/ and if you press `Submit Query` button you will see the head of the page populate.

Also I want use this piece of script to send data:

```
    function authenticate(userName, password) {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
        url: 'username:password@link to the server/update',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        //json object to sent to the authentication url
        data: '{"userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
        success: function () {

        alert("Thanks!"); 
        }
    })
}
```

Again, all I want is to be able to send that JSON data to the server. My server is set up to `update or POST` the data in the right place.

Comment: i can't make it work :) i don't know how to put them together to send that data to the server... even if i replace `data` with `data: value,`...!!??

Comment: Firstly, are you certain it's not a connection issue? If you assign an `error` function, does it get called? If so, with what error?

Comment: Though it's over a year old, I'll answer @Patrioticcow's latest question about how to do that. You see the "success" option that you sent into the ajax method? Do the same thing with "error." As in "error: MyErrorHandlingFunction" or "error: function(error) { [Error handling code here] }"

Answer (score 251, accepted):

'data' should be a stringified JavaScript object:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "userName": userName, "password" : password })
```

To send your `formData`, pass it to `stringify`:

```
data: JSON.stringify(formData)
```

Some servers also require the `application/json` content type header:

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

There's also a more detailed answer to a similar question here: [Jquery Ajax Posting JSON to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice)

Comment: @tasos I think this is what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806971/read-associative-array-from-json-in-post

Comment: Echoing the incorrectness here; this will work OK for simple scenarios, but the url-encoded message can be very problematic, especially for arrays of stuff.

Comment: @FMM and Jonas N - Can you guys help me figure out how to update my answer for correctness?  The examples in the jQuery docs (here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) make it appear as though you can post either a JS object or a string, which led me to believe that jQuery would handle all of the necessary string serialization.

Comment: Patrioticcow said: "what if i want to send the json from var value"
Unless the value is an array or an object this is not valid JSON.

Comment: Consider what happens when your data contains, for instance, a list of things: `{ foo: [1,2,3], bar: 'baz' }`. This will get form-encoded as `foo%5B%5D=1&foo%5B%5D=2&foo%5B%5D=3&bar=baz` (unescaped, it's `foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3&bar=baz`). Likely not what you want server-side.

Comment: That won't quite work if you want to post JSON to a REST service, because jQuery will be posting the content as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', while most REST services would be expecting 'application/json'; @teknopaul's answer would work much better in that case.

Comment: A "stringified JavaScript object" is a plain **String** object

Answer (score 296):

You post JSON like this

```
$.ajax(url, {
    data : JSON.stringify(myJSObject),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    type : 'POST',
    ...
```

if you pass an object as settings.data jQuery will convert it to query parameters and by default send with the data type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, probably not what you want

Answer (score 2):

In case you are sending this post request to a cross domain, you should check out this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320708/969984

Your server is not accepting the cross site post request. So the server configuration needs to be changed to allow cross site requests.

Answer (score -2):

Post async function with event.

```
//---------------------Buffers <0-9>--------------------- 
var gBuffer=[];

function GetBuffer(pIndex=0) {
    if (pIndex<0 || pIndex>9) {
        console.log('Error, pIndex out of interval <0,9>');
        return null;
    }
    if (gBuffer.length<10) {gBuffer.length=10;}
    return gBuffer[pIndex];
}

function SetBuffer(pIndex=0, pJson="") {
    if (pIndex>=10 || pIndex<0) { 
        console.log('Error, pIndex out of interval <0,9>');
        return null;
    } 
    if (gBuffer.length<10) {gBuffer.length=10;}
    return gBuffer[pIndex]=pJson;
}

//---------------------Post and generate event--------------------- 

function sleep(ms=3) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function gWait(pIndex=0, pTimeoutSec=10, pEventTag="html", pEventName="PostEvent" ) {  // async, generate event 
    if (pIndex<0 || pIndex>9) {
        console.log('Error, pIndex out of interval <0,9>');
        return;
    }
    var i=0;
    console.log('gWait start');
    while (i < 25*pTimeoutSec && GetBuffer(pIndex)==null) {
      await sleep(40);
      i++;
    }
    if (i>=25*pTimeoutSec)  {
      SetBuffer(pIndex,'{"error":"SRV error. Fetch timeout ('+pTimeoutSec+' sec)"}');
    }
    console.log('gWait stop, iteration:'+i+'/'+25*pTimeoutSec);
    $(pEventTag).trigger(pEventName,pIndex); //generate event
}

async function Post(pJSON="", pIndex=0, pTimeoutSec=10, pEventTag="html", pEventName="PostEvent") { //send JSON and return response to gArray[pIndex]
    if (pIndex<0 || pIndex>9) {
        console.log('Error, pIndex out of interval <0,9>');
        return;
    }
    var js=Trim(pJSON);
    if (js=="") { js="{}"; } //empty JSON   
    SetBuffer(pIndex,null);
    try {
        if (pTimeoutSec>0) {gWait(pIndex,pTimeoutSec,pEventTag,pEventName);} //timeout controll, and generate event
        var resp=await fetch("ajax",   //url to server example: "http://localhost:8081/api/services/tags/"
        {   method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
            body: js,
            async: true,
        })
        if (resp.status==200) {
            const result= await resp.json();
            SetBuffer(pIndex,JSON.stringify(result));
        } else {
            SetBuffer(pIndex,'{"error":"SRV error. '+resp.status+'"}');   
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
       SetBuffer(pIndex,'{"error":"SRV error. Failed to fetch."}');
    }  
    if (pTimeoutSec<=0) { $(pEventTag).trigger(pEventName,pIndex);} //generate event
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   alert('ok');
   $("html").on("PostEvent", function(event,msg){ 
      console.log(event.type+' gBuffer['+msg+']:'+GetBuffer(msg));
   });
   
   $("form").submit(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       Post('{"hello":""}');  //JSON post
       event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: The mentioned solution also deals with the error when there is no connection (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED). It also allows you to set a load timeout for all browsers if needed. It's just a part of the code that I debugged through my own GO server. The only shortcoming is the global variable, which could also be removed, but I think it has certain advantages.

Comment: When to use try-catch vs async functions, here is an article about it:
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/stop-using-try-catch-to-catch-async-await-exceptions-6e0215ace654