# Sending JSON from Java HTTPUrlConnection, but $_POST variable is empty in PHP?

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm writing an Android app and I want to send some JSON data to a PHP server. The POST request does go to the server but in my server.php script I check the $_POST variable and it is empty. TCP/IP monitor is not in Eclipse ADT and wireshark doesn't show localhost request so I can't see what is actually being sent. So does anyone have an idea what is being sent and how I can access it in PHP? Or have I made a mistake in the code somewhere?

```
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("dog", "cat");
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/server.php");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");         
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        os.write(json.toString());
        os.close();
    }
```

Comment: What response do you get from the server ?

Comment: Check the $_REQUEST to see what u get.

Comment: @t0s It's sending me back the HTML for the server.php page.

Comment: Code looks good ... grab Charles monitoring software from http://www.charlesproxy.com/download/ and set up its proxy to point to your web server. That should allow you to catch localhost requests and view their contents.

Comment: Someone deleted their response to me...their reply was correct, once I set urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") the data is showing up on the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read associative array from json in $\_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806971/read-associative-array-from-json-in-post)

Comment: os.write(json.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try it.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("dog", "cat");
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

HttpClient localDefaultHttpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost lotlisting = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/server.php");
        ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();
        localArrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json",json.toString()));
        try {
            lotlisting.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(localArrayList));
            String str = EntityUtils.toString(localDefaultHttpClient.execute(lotlisting).getEntity());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

you will get the output in str variable;

Answer (score 1):

I think is missing the flush 
Try os.flush(); after os.write(..)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use $_POST. Do something like this on user server

```
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $animals= json_decode($json,true);

    //you can do 
    echo $animals['dog'];
```