# Unable to read POST parameters

Tags: php, ios, cocoa, post, afnetworking

I am attempting to send some parameters to an API using AFNetworking. I have reduced my application code to:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"team":@"WashingtonNationals"};

[_client postPath:@"updateTeamAlert"
       parameters:params
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);
}
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

On the server I am using the following PHP to debug:

```
if (isset($_POST["team"])) {
        echo "team  set ok";
    }
    else {
        echo "team not set";
    }
```

I am consistently receiving the 'team not set' response.

When I vardump the POST I am returned:

```
'array(0) {
```

}

(an empty array I assume)?

What am I missing?

Comment: rather than debug using `isset` in that manner just `var_dump($_POST)` and see what it kicks out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you might have a similar problem to: [Read associative array from json in $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806971/read-associative-array-from-json-in-post/5807000#5807000)

if this is the case your data might be in php://input instead of in $_POST

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the trailing '/' from my postPath. :/