# AFNetworking 2.0 + iOS7: JSON POST data going to $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, not $_POST

Tags: json, post, ios7, afnetworking

I am trying to use AFNetworking 2.0 on iOS7 to send a JSON-encoded array via POST to a web server.

```
_manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];
_manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[_manager POST:@"getlistings" parameters:@{@"listings":item_ids} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
```

item_ids is an array which is passed in, it's essentially @[1234,1235], just a few numbers.
The web service which receives this request doesn't have anything set for $_POST, but the JSON I'm sending does show up in $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA. Why is this? Am I doing something wrong with my request, or is it more likely that there is a problem on the server side?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AFNetworking code looks fine, if what you want is for your server to parse JSON in the response.

I'm no PHP expert, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5807000/1445366), "`$_POST` will not be populated if the request body is not in the standard urlencoded form."

So, either follow the instructions in that answer to parse JSON, or change your `requestSerializer` to an instance of `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`, which uses standard URL encoding, instead of `AFJSONRequestSerializer`.