# Sending JSON collection to ASMX webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, json, web-services

**I have this class** :

```
public class DesignElements
{
    public List<DesignElement> Elements;
    public bool Front { set; get; }
    public string ThemeID { set; get; }


    public DesignElements()
    {
       Elements = new List<DesignElement>();
    }
}
```

result of serializing this class to page is :

```
var json=
         {
            "Elements":
               [
                {"Alignment":null,"Bold":false},
                {"Alignment":null,"Bold":false}
               ],
               "Front":true,
                "ThemeID":"9"
        };
```

problem is sending this json in page to web-service with jQuery

1. should I use the `JSON.stringify` method and sent it as as string ? if yes what is the name of argument in web-service  ?
2. can I send json as `DesignElements` object to web-service. if yes what is the name of Argument in web-service ?

Comment: Could you provide how the signature look in the webservice so we can see the names of the arguments.

Comment: @SimonEdström , what do you mean by signature ?

Comment: I mean the begining of the method like this: public string HelloWorld(string Message)

Comment: Also you need to provide how the DesignElement class looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I got in the some search specially in [Jquery Ajax Posting json to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice)

First I have to convert my object to JSON :

```
data: {DesignElements : JSON.stringify(json)}
```

and post it to webserivce

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void SaveJson(DesignElements DesignElements)
    {
    }
```

Comment: you should try data: JSON.stringify({'DesignElements' : yourobject})