# Pass json file to web service from jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, web-services

I am trying to pass a well-formatted json file as parameter to a method inside a web service. This is the method declaration:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Read GDS file", EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void ImportDataGDS(List<GDS_FLCs> FLCs)
{
// code here
}
```

And here's the **GDS_FLCs** class definition:

```
public class GDS_FLCs
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public string field2 { get; set; }
    public int field3 { get; set; }
    public string field4 { get; set; }
    public string field5 { get; set; }
    public string field6 { get; set; }
}
```

The ajax call in **readfile.aspx** (as a test, I passed a list composed of only one element):

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var values = { field1: 'Field1_value', field2: 'Field2_value', field3: 1, field4: 'Field4_value', field5: 'Y', field6: '' };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values));

        $.ajax({
            //contentType: 'application/json',
            data: { FLCs: "[" + JSON.stringify(values) + "]" },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#spinner').show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#spinner').hide();
            },
            url: "WebService.asmx/ImportDataGDS",
            success: function () {
                alert("Data import successful");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error: Import failed.");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

According to Chrome console, this is the data that is being sent to the web service:

> FLCs:[{ "field1": "Field1_value", "field2": "Field2_value", "field3":
>   1, "field4": "Field4_value", "field5": 'Y', "field6": '' }]

However, this is the returned response:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ImportDataGDS Web Service method
>   name is not valid.   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type,
>   HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
>   Boolean& abortProcessing)

As a first step, I would like to get this to work (pass a hardcoded custom list as argument to the web service) and then work on passing the entire file to the web service. I haven't found a way to pass an entire file as argument to the web service using ajax. Is there another way? I checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768071/sending-json-collection-to-asmx-webservice) but it didn't help.

Any hints or ideas will be more than welcome. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1:** I changed the declaration of the method to static, but it didn't work:

```
public static void ImportDataGDS(List<GDS_FLCs> FLCs)
{
// code here
}
```

(same error message as before)

**EDIT #2:** Walter's suggestion pointed me in the right direction. I ended up sending the array as string and then deserialized it using the web method.

Now off to the second part of my question, now I need the ajax call read a file and send it to the web method. Here's what I tried:

```
$.get("test.js", function (data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        data: { FLCs: data },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: "POST",
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $('#spinner').show();
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            $('#spinner').hide();
                        },
                        url: "WebService.asmx/ImportDataGDS",
                        success: function () {
                            alert("Data import successful");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Error: Import failed.");
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Where **test.js** is the file that I want to pass to the web service.

At first this seemed to work, but Chrome console (and Firebug as well) indicated that the file had been read by the $.get method (and I could easily see that fact on the console) but was not passed to the web service by $.ajax. I believe I am doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Comment: Shouldn't your webmethod be declared as static? Not quite sure though

Comment: yes, it should be set to static.

Comment: When you debug the page do you get inside the webmethod at all?

Comment: @Dean.DePue No, I do not get inside the webmethod at all. I also declared the method as static (see Edit #1), with the same result. Any other clues?

Comment: OK, just try to place a WebMethod call in your page code behind and change the ajax call - does it hit the method?

Comment: try this: `data: JSON.stringify({ FLCs: [values] }),`

Comment: @WalterStabosz it worked! Your idea pointed me in the right direction. I sent the data to the web service as a string and deserialized it there. The first part of my question is solved. Now I need to work on having the ajax call send a complete json file to the web service.

Comment: Now I need to send a complete file from the ajax call to the web service. Please see above EDIT #2 to see what I've tried.

Comment: @Dean.DePue thank you as well for your help with this so far!

Comment: Is your signature for `ImportDataGDS` still `ImportDataGDS(List<GDS_FLCs> FLCs)` or did you change it to `ImportDataGDS(string FLCs)` ? You shouldn't have to read FLCs as a `string`, .NET should just deserialize the JSON as long as it's correctly formatted and matches the `GDS_FLCs` class definition. One thing you might want to try is write a WebMethod with the signature `ImportDataGDS(GDS_FLCs FLC)` and see if you can get .NET to deserialize a single `GDS_FLCs` object. Then try practicing on Lists with something like `ImportNumbers(List<int> numbers)`, then put the two together.

Comment: @WalterStabosz, yes, I changed the signature to ImportDataGDS(string FLCs) but will certainly give your new suggestion a try and get back here with the results! Any ideas on the second part of the question?