# JQuery Ajax :"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027Object\u0027" error

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, web-services

I am trying to post a form to my web service with no great success so far.
Before posting to the server I am converting the form to an object.
I get an error when posting the form `Object` to my `Asmx` web service.

My Ajax:

```
 var formObject = $(form).serializeObject();
 var formData = JSON.stringify(formObject);
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "./Service.asmx/PostAutomaticRule",
          data: { myObject: formData },
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

My asmx:

```
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public void PostAutomaticRule(MyClass myObject)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(myObject);
    }


}

[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public string automaticRuleName { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string increaseBudgetByValue { get; set; }
    public string increaseBudgetMaximumBudget { get; set; }
}
```

More information:
When debugging these are the values:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it like this:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "./Service.asmx/PostAutomaticRule",
          data: "{'myObject': "+formData+"}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code for the **data** parameter in your ajax call:

```
data: {myObject: JSON.stringify($(form).serializeObject())},
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [sending-json-collection-to-asmx-webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768071/sending-json-collection-to-asmx-webservice)

I'll say change to:

```
data: {Object : JSON.stringify($(form).serializeObject())}
```

or

```
data: {myObject : JSON.stringify($(form).serializeObject())}
```

But you might have to create a more specific class.