# How can keep and access json file in current web page?

Tags: jquery, json, asmx

I want to store page data in a json file and when I click a button i want to send it to a web service. How can I do It. Direct me.

Thanx..

Comment: Be specific about your requirement... what you want to do and what you tried till now..??

Comment: I can call web service using jquery and i can create json file. i don't know intermediate steps.

Comment: okay than you can use $.ajax() function of jquery to send request to web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I store json in input hidden in html

Answer (score 2):

If you use html5, you can use `localStorage["any_key"] = "your_json_string"` to save your data in the browser and fetch the data by using `localStorage["any_key"]`.

Comment: Is there any way I can store json string in html?

Comment: Why do you want to do like this? I don't know any way to store the html. However, you can use javascript to load the data from localStorage and change the html content.

Comment: I store json in input hidden in html.

Answer (score 2):

how do you plan to store file on the client? You can serialize the data into json and send it to the desired webservice

here are some useful posts

[**let me google that for you**](http://bit.ly/y5FfIn)

[Jquery Ajax Posting json to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice)

http://francstratton.com/jQueryAJAXCall.aspx

Comment: I would follow this way too. +1

Comment: can you tell me better way of store file on the client? I have no clear way.

Comment: you can explore `localStorage` as @zsxwing mentioned or you can use cookies, you will have to serialize the data and store that data in localStorage or cookie

Comment: I store json in input hidden in html.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a json file, but if you want to send information in an `array` to a WebService via `jQuery.ajax()` you can do it:

```
// First you construct an array (can be multidimensional)
var arr_data = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 21,
  phones: [ 12345678, 87654321 ]
};

$.ajax('service-page.php', {
  data: arr_data,
  success: function() {
    alert('Content saved!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct your existing problem you should save the data not in the file, but in the DOM of the page. If you want for example that the saved data will have any association with a button you can use [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to save the information. For example

```
// save data as object
$('#myButtonId').data('forMyWebService', { myType: 'test', count: 40 });
```

or

```
// save data as JSON string
$('#myButtonId').data('forMyWebService', '{"myType":"test","count":40}');
```