# html canvas+ Javascript on client side and python on serverside

Tags: javascript, python, client, diagramming

I am trying to create a small tool very similar to https://www.circuitlab.com/ 
I am thinking of using HTML5 canvas to create diagrams ( possibly with kinetic.js) and make use of Javascript to create graphics. I want each diagram to be mapped to a model which will run on the server side when called. For this I want to call python functions from java script and return the output of python functions to the same javascript code.

I have looked at this forum for similar questions. I found many but the answers were not related to what I want.

If I go to python based web packages like cherrypy or mod_python most documentation deals with creating HTML/javascript pages as output with a new url.

I do not want to go for pyjamas or skulpt.

Is it possible to do what I want using Javascript/Jquery/Ajax ?

I have been learning Javascript for a week now, Even though I am confident about my coding abilities, I am not familiar with the web terminologies.

Comment: this question is too broad for stack overflow. you're looking for the general concept of REST services, aka sending information from client to server via http calls. there's lots of ways to achieve that.

Comment: Ah thanks for directing me, I will look into REST services. 
Should this question go to some other QA website under stackexchange?

Comment: here's a [simple example how to send/receive objects between javascript/python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12812289/4279)

Comment: That looks pretty good :). I was looking more into cherrypy + pyhole. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think this question is good on any exchange site. It's too broad. You need to narrow it down to a specific need, and if that need is just passing json between client and server, that's not specific enough.

Comment: The magic word I needed was REST service. Sometimes when you come from a different background you do not know the terms you have to search for, This kills a lot of momentum.  I feel that this type of question should be valid on some type of q/A site related to stack exchange. Perhaps there is a business opportunity in this gap ;) .