# What is the correct format for sending data for jQuery ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, .net

When executing an ajax request using jQuery I am not sure how to add a variable to the data that is being sent to the server. Sending a request with a static string works fine:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

                var inputtext = $("#txtInput").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Webform1.aspx/Function",
                    data: "{'ans':'hello'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.d);
                    }

                });
            });
```

The above calls the .net function and then produces a msgbox with the response string.

How can I replace the hard coded string 'hello' with a variable such as the inputtext variable above.

The following does not work and results in 500 errors that relate to json parsing:

```
{'ans':inputtext}
```

<strike>{ans:inputtext}</strike>

```
{"ans":inputtext}
```

(ans is the name of the function parameter)

**Edit:**

To process the request server side I just use the .net WebMethod attribute for the function, which works with the hard-coded string request in the above example but simply returns the entire html page when passed a variable using data: {ans:inputtext}:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Function(string ans)
    {

        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: [`"{'ans':'hello'}"` is not valid JSON!](http://jsonlint.com) Strings and object keys in JSON must be delimited by **double** quotes. jQuery is likely encoding that string as JSON again, which suggests something is wonky in your _server_ code; the client looks fine to me.

Comment: @MattBall Apparently when json passing data to a webservice function you need to first convert it into a string which why {ans: intputtext} wasn't working for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var inputtext = $("#txtInput").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Webform1.aspx/Function",
        data: {ans: inputtext},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
});
```

As long as `#btnSubmit` is'nt an actual submit button in a form.

Comment: @MattBall - I noticed that, but it's still the right way to do it.

Comment: @adeneo `alert( msg.d ); // "Right way!"` ? ;)

Comment: @roXon - who knows what that is, could be a string, the OP does'nt seem to have any issues with that, yet ?

Comment: @adeneo Perhaps this is more of a server-side issue - but your code (which i tried just now) seems to not invoke the function, rather the server simply responds with the entire page, whereas sending the static string {'ans':'hello'} produces the desired result - any ideas?

Comment: You're doing something to parse the string that works, on the serverside, that does'nt work with a regular object, which should be converted to a string when sent as a POST request as far as I know. You should post how you retrieve the value on the serverside as well. I guess Matt Ball was right, again!

Comment: _"I guess Matt Ball was right, again!"_ I'm Matt Ball, and I approve this message. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

The value for your data option looks odd.  I usually do it the following way:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Webform1.aspx/Function",
                    data: {'ans':'hello'},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    }

                });
```

i removed                     dataType: "json", i think json is the default anyway

Comment: its from the original post,  i noticed it too.  i guess i'll remove it

Comment: This doesn't seem right. JSON requires keys and values to be delimited by double-quotes, not single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the submit event instead of button click, then it'll be easier to get a reference to form, then call .serialize on the form, which will include all of the form fields.  As long as the [name] attribute of the input is "ans" then it will end up in the json with that name.  My example assumes you add "answerForm" class to the form which you want this behavior for.

```
.on('submit', '.answerFornm', function (e) {
  $.ajax({
  ...
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  ...
```