# testing a Post in WebAPI from a form with JSON

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I have some sample JSON I want to post to my WebAPI fo testing but I cannot see to get it to deserilaize my object I am passing in.

Here is my form:

```
<form  action="/api/orders" method="post" >
              <textarea type="text" id="order" name="order"></textarea>
              <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is my method:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Model.Order order)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<Order>(HttpStatusCode.Created, order);
            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = order.OrderID });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }
```

Here is what I paste in the form for submission:

```
{
  "ShipToContactPhone" : "9999999999",
  "ContactPhone" : "9999999999",
  "IsPlaced" : 0,
  "ContainerName" : null,
  "Terms" : "3",
  "ShipDate" : null,
  "OrderGUID" : "6D55FB6E-36A2-43F3-8316-2BE740ACC8E1",
  "CatalogName" : null,
  "ShipToCountry" : "USA",
  "SalesRepID" : 0,
  "OrderType" : null,
  "ShipVia" : null,
  "IsContainer" : null,
  "BillingAddress1" : "TEST ACCOUNT",
  "BillingCity" : "BROOK",
  "CustomerID" : 721182,
  "BillingAddress2" : "",
  "OrderStatus" : "Accept",
  "TaxTotal" : 0,
  "Source" : null,
  "Discount" : 0,
  "OrderDate" : "3\/8\/13",
  "CustomerNumber" : "26",
  "OrderTotal" : 2160,
  "ShippingTotal" : 0,
  "ShipToZip" : "07663",
  "CurrencyCode" : "USD",
  "TaxRate" : 0,
  "Origin" : null,
  "CancelDate" : null,
  "WrittenByName" : "(null)",
  "BillingState" : "NJ",
  "Exported" : null,
  "ShipToAddress1" : "6 ANYWHERE STREET",
  "ShipToAddress2" : "",
  "Notes" : "",
  "FreightTerm" : null,
  "ShipToContactEmail" : "test@test.com",
  "ContactEmail" : "test@test.com",
  "ShipToFax" : "9999999999",
  "ContactName" : "",
  "PONumber" : "",
  "ShipToContactName" : null,
  "WrittenForName" : null,
  "CatalogCode" : null,
  "ManufacturerID" : 3456,
  "ShipToCompanyName" : "TEST",
  "ShipToState" : "NJ",
  "isDefault" : 1,
  "PriceLevel" : 5,
  "ShipToCity" : "BROOK",
  "ContainerCubes" : 0,
  "WrittenForRepnumber" : null,
  "MarketName" : "",
  "DoNotShipBefore" : null,
  "RepNumber" : null,
  "FOB" : null,
  "IsDeleted" : null,
  "SubTotal" : 0,
  "ContactFax" : "9999999999",
  "BillingZip" : "07663",
  "CustomerName" : "TEST",
  "ExportDate" : null,
  "OrderID" : 0,
  "WrittenForRepNumber" : null,
  "BillingCountry" : "USA"
}
```

I think this is probably because the content-type is not **`application/json`** coming from the form.

How can I simply test this and get it working?

Comment: How is your class `Order`?

Comment: simple class, added some example data above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function. Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6323528/2124070)

Comment: Yes, JQuery would be a good option. A web browser submits a form using form-url encoding.