# Serialize an object containing a child object via JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new with JSON and I try to pass some data in a JsonResult method located in my controller. 
The method accepts an AModel as a parameter. This AModel is defined with some properties, and a BModel.

So, I wrote :

```
function loadDatas() {

    var values = 
    {
        "Title" : "The title",
        "Text" : "Blahblahblah",
        "BModel" : 
        {
            "Summary" : "lorem ipsum",
            "Page" : "15"
        }
    };

    $.post("@Url.Action("Load", "MyController")",values,function(data)
    {
        // do stuff;
    });
```

And my Load method is defined as :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Load(AModel test)
{
    return Json(test); //dummy example, just serialize back the AModel object
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on Load's opening brace, test.Title and test.Text have the good values, but test.BModel.Summary and test.BModel.Page are null.

The worst part in this problem is if I put an alert(values.HousingModel.Summary); the value displayed is the good one ! Why is it not send correctly to my method whereas values.Title and values.Text are ??

I used this link to understand JSON format (http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-json-serialization/) and mine seems valid... Isn't it ?

Thanks for your help

Alex

Comment: You should post the C# definition of `AModel`. The serializer bases its behavior on that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Ajax Posting json to webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *My Working Code*

**Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Json(AModel test)
{
    return Json(new { Success = true });
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url         :    "@Url.Action("Load", "MyController")",
    contentType :    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType    :    "json",
    type        :    "POST",
    data        :    JSON.stringify({test: values})
})}).done(function (result) {
    //Success
}).fail(function (result) {
    //Failed
}).always(function(result) { 
    //Always
});
```

**Models**

```
public class AModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public BModel BModel { get; set; }
}

public class BModel
{
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string Page { get; set; }
}
```

**Mistakes**

1. Serialization was mising
2. Content Type was missing
3. Type was missing

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed and educational answer! I tried the three mistakes, but not in the same time... Now I have a working sample, I'll be able to go on !

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing hour Model we can't give you definitive answer but...
is it possible that your BModel.Page is an integer in C#?  If so the Model binder can't set your values on that SubObject with your javascript string value...