# Invalid JSON primitive making AJAX call

Tags: asp.net, jquery, kendo-ui

I am getting an InvalidJSONprimitive error that's driving me crazy. Here's the code - any ideas what I am missing?

I've also tried passing the ID parameter as a string (`data: '{"ID":"' + 999 + '"}'`), and changing dataType to text - same error.

Thanks in advance!

```
var params = {ID: 999};

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddl').kendoComboBox({
        filter: "contains",
        dataTextField : "DBA",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(params),
                    url: "../webservices/data.asmx/GetDBA",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is probably being URL encoded; see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20229197/2001735) for one approach. Alternatively, using this should work too, I think:

```
var params = {
    ID: 999
};
```

(make sure the parameter name is the same as in your server-side service)...

```
transport: {
    read: {
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: params,
        url: "../webservices/data.asmx/GetDBA",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    parameterMap: function (data, type) {
        return kendo.stringify(data);
    }
}
```

If those solutions don't work, you should inspect the string that is arriving at the server and append that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

quotes around ID

var params = {'ID': 999};

Comment: Tried single and double quotes. No dice. :(

Comment: and your not putting the whole thing in quotes, are you?

Comment: if you do JSON.stringify({'ID': 999}) and put it in params do you get the error?