# jQuery ajax webmethod error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have a webmethod returning an object and I am having difficulty accessing the object returned from the jQuery Ajax method. I would like to access the HighlightResults and display in a repeater. I keep getting the error: There was an error processing the request. Internal server error.

My object is:

```
  public class SearchResults
  {
    internal SearchResults()
    {

    }

    public virtual IQueryable<Document> DocumentResults { get; internal set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<Page> PageResults { get; internal set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<Word> WordResults { get; internal set; }
    public ICollection<String> HighlightResults { get; internal set; }
    public int QueryTime { get; internal set; }
    public int TotalResults { get; internal set; }

}
```

And my ajax function:

```
var query = String($('[id$=txtSearch]').val());            
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Viewer.aspx/GetHighlightResults",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({docID: docid, query: query, 
                  pageNumber: 1, resultsPerPage: 10}),
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Success!!");                 
                var data = response.d;

                // none of these are displaying....
                alert(String(data));
                alert(String(data.HighlightResults));
                alert(String(data.HighlightResults[0]));

                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    alert(item);
                    alert(item.HighlightResults);

                    $("#search-results").append("<b>" + item + "</b>");
                })
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("responseText=" + xhr.responseText + 
                      "\n textStatus=" + status + "\n errorThrown=" + error);
            }
        });
```

And finally, my web method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static SearchResults GetHighlightResults(String docID, String query, 
                  String pageNumber, String resultsPerPage)
    {
        SearchResults results = null;
        try
        {
            ArchiveSearcher searcher = new ArchiveSearcher();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query) && Convert.ToInt32(docID) > 0 && 
                Convert.ToInt32(pageNumber) > 0 && Convert.ToInt32(resultsPerPage) > 0)
            {
                results = searcher.SearchDocument(Convert.ToInt32(docID), query, 
                Convert.ToInt32(pageNumber), Convert.ToInt32(resultsPerPage)); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception.
            ArchiveViewer.Logic.ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "GetSearchResults in Viewer.aspx.cs");
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** If I return the `ICollection<String> Highlight` results from the web method, I can access it from the jquery ajax function using:

```
success: function (response) {
    var data = response.d;
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
         alert(item);
....
```

I think my issue is related to how I access the entire SearchResults object. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT 2:** I've commented out everything in my ajax success function and it still fails. So the issue is with passing back the class. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it hit the webmethod if you debug?

Comment: Yes, and I am returning something. But it doesn't hit alert("Success!!"); I get the error instead.

Comment: It looks like it. I'm getting the following: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:5148/Viewer.aspx/GetSearchResults

Comment: Then it does not hit your function...try to change your data to only one and pass that to function with one parameter..

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly question but, if it hits my breakpoint in my webfunction, then how is it not hitting it? Also, see edit above. If I return collection<string> it works fine.

Comment: @Zaki - see edit 2 above...

Comment: I created a test project and your code works fine...I get the alert.see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh!!! I figured it out. Thank you Zaki, you nudged me in the right direction!!

I didn't have any errors in the web method, but exception occurred when my object was being serialized to JSON. The issue is with serializing `IQueryable<T>` in my class. I've changed it to `List<T>` and everything is working now. (A day of my life gone!)

Just to be complete, the correct way to access the objects being returned in the client is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Viewer.aspx/GetSearchResults",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ docID: docid, query: query, pageNumber: 1, resultsPerPage: 10 }),
    success: function (response) {
        var data = response.d.HighlightResults;
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            $("#search-results").append("<b>" + item + "</b>");
        })
    } 
......
```

Comment: I missed : contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"  - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Through Jquery ajax you pass the JSON.stringify data but in your method you get it as a normal string

Check with that reference link https://stackoverflow.com/a/6323528/2641723

Comment: I know that the way I pass in the data is correct. I do the same thing in another method. I'm pretty sure my issue is with retrieving and accessing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing in a test project and it returned success. I can see the alert firing:

here is what I changed in object:

```
  public virtual IQueryable<string> DocumentResults { get; internal set; }
  public virtual IQueryable<Page> PageResults { get; internal set; }
  public virtual IQueryable<string> WordResults { get; internal set; }
```

then in ajax :

```
  data: JSON.stringify({
                docID: 'test',
                query: 'tet2',
                pageNumber: 1,
                resultsPerPage: 10
            }),
```

and :

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static SearchResults GetHighlightResults(String docID, String query,
                      String pageNumber, String resultsPerPage)
        {
            SearchResults results = null;
            try
            {
                 results = new SearchResults();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception.
                //ArchiveViewer.Logic.ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "GetSearchResults in Viewer.aspx.cs");
            }
            return results;
        }
```

I suggest you check that there are not any exceptions in the webmethod.

Comment: I need to send back my custom classes (Document, and Word). Unfortunately, string is not enough. :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue , posting my solution :

jsp file :

```html
<c:forEach var="myMap" items="${myMap}" varStatus="status">
        <tr><td>
                ${myMap.key}
            <c:forEach var="info" items="${myMap.value}">
                URL ${info}
                <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>

                </select>
                <button type="button" onclick="test()">Update</button>

            </c:forEach>
        </td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Controller file :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "postData", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String putService(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> myMap) {
 // perform operations  
  return String;
}
```

js file:

```js
function test(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your url',
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({"Key":"Value"}),
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Operation Success');
        }
    });
```