# Error while sending array of json to web service in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json

I am trying to send a bunch of my IndexedDB datas(Tables) as **`JSON` to my ASP.NET WebService**.. I ve tried everything but couldnt resolve it.. Here is my error messafe from my console Window..

```
function Insert(Applicant) {
  $.ajax({ type: "POST", async: false, url: "/WebService1.asmx/Insert",
  //datatype: "text", 
    data: JSON.stringify({ ApplicantList: Applicant }),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(str) { alert("Message: "+str.d); },
     error: function(err) { alert("Error: "+err.d); } }); 
 }
```

**Error**

```
ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
Message: "Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IndexedDB.Applicant]'"
StackTrace: "   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Obj
{"Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IndexedDB.Applicant]\u0027","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToType(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

**IndexedDB Code**

```
             cursor.onsuccess = function(e) {
                var result = e.target.result;
                console.log(result);

                if(result) {
                    if(json == "") {
                        json += " [ ";
                    }
                    else {
                        json += ",";
                    }

                    json += " {\"Id\":\""+result.value["id"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Applicant_Name\":\""+result.value["AM_Applicant_Name"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Father_Name\":\""+result.value["AM_Father_Name"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Mobile_No\":\""+result.value["AM_Mobile_No"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Address\":\""+result.value["AM_Address"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Address1\":\""+result.value["AM_Address1"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Address2\":\""+result.value["AM_Address2"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Pin_Code\":\""+result.value["AM_Pin_Code"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"District_Code\":\""+result.value["AM_District_Code"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Taluk_Code\":\""+result.value["AM_Taluk_Code"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Hobli_Code\":\""+result.value["AM_Hobli_Code"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Village_Code\":\""+result.value["AM_Village_Code"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Habitation_Code\":\""+result.value["AM_Habitation_Code"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Reservation_Code\":\""+result.value["AM_Reservation_Code"]+"\", ";
                    json += " \"Caste_Code\":\""+result.value["AM_Caste_Code"]+"\"} ";

                    result.continue();
                }
            }
            cursor.onerror = function(e) {
                console.log(e.target.error.name);
                alert(e.target.error.name);
            }
            trans.oncomplete = function() {
                if(json != "") {
                    json += "];";
                    //alert(json);
                    Insert(json);
                }
            }
```

**Web Service**

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string Insert(List<Applicant> ApplicantList)
    {
        string value = "";
        if (ApplicantList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in ApplicantList)
            {
                value += item.Applicant_Name + " ";
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

I am passing below json value to my web service

```
{"ApplicantList":" [  
 {\"Id\":\"14\",  \"Applicant_Name\":\"arun\",
  \"Father_Name\":\"gopi\",  \"Mobile_No\":\"7875645756\",  \"Address\":\"rter\", 
  \"Address1\":\"werty\",  \"Address2\":\"rter\",  \"Pin_Code\":\"674564\", 
  \"District_Code\":\"8\",  \"Taluk_Code\":\"5\",  \"Hobli_Code\":\"2\", 
  \"Village_Code\":\"642100\",  \"Habitation_Code\":\"0\",  \"Reservation_Code\":\"2\", 
  \"Caste_Code\":\"383\"} , 
 {\"Id\":\"12\",  \"Applicant_Name\":\"asha\", 
  \"Father_Name\":\"qwasha\",  \"Mobile_No\":\"8968567675\",  \"Address\":\"asdfgh\", 
  \"Address1\":\"fjk\",  \"Address2\":\"dfjhk\",  \"Pin_Code\":\"765765\", 
  \"District_Code\":\"9\",  \"Taluk_Code\":\"3\",  \"Hobli_Code\":\"2\",  
  \"Village_Code\":\"668800\",  \"Habitation_Code\":\"0\",  \"Reservation_Code\":\"5\", 
  \"Caste_Code\":\"788\"} , 
 {\"Id\":\"13\",  \"Applicant_Name\":\"asha\", 
  \"Father_Name\":\"mani\",  \"Mobile_No\":\"9757543346\",  \"Address\":\"sdf\", 
  \"Address1\":\"sdfsd\",  \"Address2\":\"gdf\",  \"Pin_Code\":\"565664\", 
  \"District_Code\":\"8\",  \"Taluk_Code\":\"6\",  \"Hobli_Code\":\"1\", 
  \"Village_Code\":\"623600\",  \"Habitation_Code\":\"0\",  \"Reservation_Code\":\"4\", 
  \"Caste_Code\":\"751\"} 
];"}
```

**Applicant Class**

```
public class Applicant
{
    public Applicant() { }

    public string Applicant_Name { get; set; }
    public string Father_Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Mobile_No { get; set; }
    public string Pin_Code { get; set; }
    public string District_Code { get; set; }
    public string Taluk_Code { get; set; }
    public string Hobli_Code { get; set; }
    public string Village_Code { get; set; }
    public string Habitation_Code { get; set; }
    public string Reservation_Code { get; set; }
    public string Caste_Code { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Need to see your code here

Comment: Instead of posting code in comments try editing the question itself, also as per best of my knowledge you can not post a list from json

Comment: How can I get my json object in my WebService?? Which Datatype will be correct for that??

Comment: Not related to IDB, removed tag

Comment: try changing your method parameter type from `List<Applicant> ApplicantList` to `String ApplicantList`..And what is applicant in your code??

Comment: sorry I cant understand your point.. can you tell me clearly??..

Comment: in ur code `data: JSON.stringify({ ApplicantList: Applicant }),`  ...what is `Applicant` ?? Please update that in ur question

Comment: Applicant is my json array that I am sending it in my trans.oncomplete method

Comment: can u update your `Applicant` class too??

Comment: sorry I cant understand

Comment: `public string Insert(List<Applicant> ApplicantList)` here u have an `Applicant` class rite? Can u post dat..

Comment: In order to split my json object and get individual datas from my json array, I m using that Applicant class.. Actually, I m sending multiple  datas at a time in json array, and I want to split it and save it to my DB

Comment: I replaced List<Applicant> ApplicantList to String and it is accepting, but how can I retrieve my individual records from the String..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not the same question so I am not reportin it as a duplicate. But you will be able to find your answer on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice) as you seem to be making the similar mistake. Try changing your js function and JSON creation as following:

```
var Applicant = 
[  
 {\"Id\":\"14\",  \"Applicant_Name\":\"arun\",\"Father_Name\":\"gopi\",  \"Mobile_No\":\"7875645756\",  \"Address\":\"rter\", \"Address1\":\"werty\", \"Address2\":\"rter\",  \"Pin_Code\":\"674564\",   \"District_Code\":\"8\",  \"Taluk_Code\":\"5\",  \"Hobli_Code\":\"2\",   \"Village_Code\":\"642100\",  \"Habitation_Code\":\"0\",  \"Reservation_Code\":\"2\",   \"Caste_Code\":\"383\"} 
, 
 {\"Id\":\"12\",  \"Applicant_Name\":\"asha\", \"Father_Name\":\"qwasha\",  \"Mobile_No\":\"8968567675\",  \"Address\":\"asdfgh\", \"Address1\":\"fjk\",  \"Address2\":\"dfjhk\",  \"Pin_Code\":\"765765\", \"District_Code\":\"9\",  \"Taluk_Code\":\"3\",  \"Hobli_Code\":\"2\", \"Village_Code\":\"668800\",  \"Habitation_Code\":\"0\",  \"Reservation_Code\":\"5\", \"Caste_Code\":\"788\"} 
, 
 {\"Id\":\"13\",  \"Applicant_Name\":\"asha\", \"Father_Name\":\"mani\",  \"Mobile_No\":\"9757543346\",  \"Address\":\"sdf\", \"Address1\":\"sdfsd\",  \"Address2\":\"gdf\",  \"Pin_Code\":\"565664\", \"District_Code\":\"8\",  \"Taluk_Code\":\"6\",  \"Hobli_Code\":\"1\", \"Village_Code\":\"623600\",  \"Habitation_Code\":\"0\",  \"Reservation_Code\":\"4\", \"Caste_Code\":\"751\"} 
];


function Insert() {
  $.ajax({ type: "POST", async: false, url: "/WebService1.asmx/Insert",
  //datatype: "text", 
    data: JSON.stringify({ ApplicantList: Applicant }),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(str) { alert("Message: "+str.d); },
     error: function(err) { alert("Error: "+err.d); } }); 
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does you Inser function get Applicant, and please post the code by updating your question only.

Comment: Hi @ShashankChaturvedi, Now I have added my code, now go through it and rectify my bugs...

Comment: One last thing, post the code for WebService1.asmx/Insert that is your Insert webmethod. And also the exact line where you are actually getting error.

Comment: already posted below my indexedDB code.. My WebMethod is accepting only string that is the problem..

Comment: I have updated my answer, make the changes accordingly.