# Convert JS Object to form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipartform-data, form-data

How can I can convert my JS Object to `FormData`?

The reason why I want to do this is, I have an object that I constructed out of the ~100 form field values.

```
var item = {
   description: 'Some Item',
   price : '0.00',
   srate : '0.00',
   color : 'red',
   ...
   ...
}
```

Now I am asked to add the upload file functionality to my form which, of-course is impossible via JSON and so I am planning on moving to `FormData`. So is there any way that I can convert my JS object to `FormData`?

Comment: can you share your work/progress?

Comment: how about JSON.stringify()?

Comment: @Sunny — That will produce a JSON text in a string. That is not a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object.

Comment: Yes you can, you can append to formData objects.

Comment: can you show us what do you mean by FormData? any specific format?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: check https://github.com/foo123/serialiser.js to serialise complex / nested form fields to formData, object, json, url-encoded data (author)

Comment: I ended up finding it easier to post JSON as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6323528/470749

Answer (score 291, accepted):

If you have an object, you can easily create a FormData object and append the names and values from that object to formData.

You haven't posted any code, so it's a general example;

```
var form_data = new FormData();

for ( var key in item ) {
    form_data.append(key, item[key]);
}

$.ajax({
    url         : 'http://example.com/upload.php',
    data        : form_data,
    processData : false,
    contentType : false,
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(data){
    // do stuff
});
```

There are more examples in the documentation on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: It's safer to use Object.keys() instead of the for-in loop, as you might get unexpected results, as the for-in iterates on inherited properties as well.

Comment: @Lior - `item` is a regular object created by the OP, so it shouldn't have any properties that are not it's own, unless someone made the mistake of prototyping something onto the Object constructor, in which case you would be in a world of trouble, and it's not something we should have to protect against.

Comment: Actually, it's considered a best practice, especially if you're giving a solution to someone which you don't know the context and the environment he uses, a simple warning would have done the job. Remember that the solutions you give on SO aren't just for the OP but for potentially thousands of other eyes looking for a solution, which won't break their code.

Comment: @Lior - it's just adding the key/value pairs to FormData, adding a prototyped property wont break anything, and using `Object.keys` is not the answer, as you shouldn't have to get the keys as an array, then iterate over the keys to get the values, you should be using a `for..in` loop.

Comment: Of course it will, you don't know what the server is expecting...
for...in in JS is problamtic, the solution doesn't have to be Object.keys(), it could be hasOwnProperty(), but it needs to be at least a warning.

Comment: @Lior - If your server breaks when it receives one more key/value pair in a POST request, you're doing it wrong. I think the answer is fine, and I'm not going to change it to use `Object.keys` or `hasOwnProperty()` as the object is posted in the question and shouldn't need any of those. The reason you sometimes see `hasOwnProperty` used in plugins etc. is because you never know what some people might do to the `Object` constructor, but for the most part people shouldn't have to test for inherited properties on objects they've created, that's a sign that you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't agree some third party libs change native prototypes, and if you give an answer you should warn about potential pitfalls. But never mind, this isn't going anywhere... p.s.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Both of you guys have missed my point, and for some reason you instead just got really emotional about the whole thing (at least adeneo kept it cool and professional). There was no attempt to educate anyone (although I think the idea you can't learn from someone even though you have "more than 100 times the reputation and 100 times the number of answers" is absurd...especially when SO is all about learning).

Comment: What would be the way to convert a complex json object (which contains nested objects and arrays) into a FormData object ?

Comment: whats the best way to convert FromData to a json object to be send to the server?

Comment: If you need JSON, you should create JSON, not a formData object.

Comment: I think that this will not work if `item[key]` is an object or an array. Please take a look at my answer

Comment: Of course it won't work with nested objects, one would need to iterate differently depending on the data structure one has.

Comment: @adeneo Here's a more modern approach, while also avoiding looping through and appending prototype properties: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx967tkv/5/).

Comment: @adeneo can you update this to use `fetch()` instead of jquery please?

Answer (score 168):

With ES6 and a more functional programming approach @adeneo's answer could looks like this:

```
function getFormData(object) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => formData.append(key, object[key]));
    return formData;
}
```

And alternatively using `.reduce()` and arrow-functions:

```
const getFormData = object => Object.keys(object).reduce((formData, key) => {
    formData.append(key, object[key]);
    return formData;
}, new FormData());
```

Comment: I just ran a performance-comparison for your two answers, and the `.reduce()` one is 1-2% faster. https://jsbench.me/m3kg87fxvt/1

Comment: It's possible to add a parameter that allow us to avoid specific keys in the object?

Comment: There should be a built-in method for that. Or even it should be a parameter to the `FormData` constructor.

Comment: Also, using `Object.entries` would be even more functional here, as `object` is outside function call in `object[key]`.

Comment: That's NOT recursive

Answer (score 104):

This function adds all data from object to FormData

ES6 version from @developer033:

```
function buildFormData(formData, data, parentKey) {
  if (data && typeof data === 'object' && !(data instanceof Date) && !(data instanceof File) && !(data instanceof Blob)) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      buildFormData(formData, data[key], parentKey ? `${parentKey}[${key}]` : key);
    });
  } else {
    const value = data == null ? '' : data;

    formData.append(parentKey, value);
  }
}

function jsonToFormData(data) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  
  buildFormData(formData, data);
  
  return formData;
}

const my_data = {
  num: 1,
  falseBool: false,
  trueBool: true,
  empty: '',
  und: undefined,
  nullable: null,
  date: new Date(),
  name: 'str',
  another_object: {
    name: 'my_name',
    value: 'whatever'
  },
  array: [
    {
      key1: {
        name: 'key1'
      }
    }
  ]
};

jsonToFormData(my_data)
```

jQuery version:

```
function appendFormdata(FormData, data, name){
    name = name || '';
    if (typeof data === 'object'){
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            if (name == ''){
                appendFormdata(FormData, value, index);
            } else {
                appendFormdata(FormData, value, name + '['+index+']');
            }
        })
    } else {
        FormData.append(name, data);
    }
}


var formData = new FormData(),
    your_object = {
        name: 'test object',
        another_object: {
            name: 'and other objects',
            value: 'whatever'
        }
    };
appendFormdata(formData, your_object);
```

Comment: Just a small edit, add `!(data instanceof Blob)` for support Blob image.

Answer (score 33):

The other answers were incomplete for me. I started from @Vladimir Novopashin answer and modified it. Here are the things, that I needed and bug I found:

- Support for file
- Support for array
- Bug: File inside complex object needs to be added with `.prop` instead of `[prop]`. For example, `formData.append('photos[0][file]', file)` didn't work on google chrome, while
  `formData.append('photos[0].file', file)` worked
- Ignore some properties in my object

The following code should work on IE11 and evergreen browsers.

```
function objectToFormData(obj, rootName, ignoreList) {
    var formData = new FormData();

    function appendFormData(data, root) {
        if (!ignore(root)) {
            root = root || '';
            if (data instanceof File) {
                formData.append(root, data);
            } else if (Array.isArray(data)) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    appendFormData(data[i], root + '[' + i + ']');
                }
            } else if (typeof data === 'object' && data) {
                for (var key in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if (root === '') {
                            appendFormData(data[key], key);
                        } else {
                            appendFormData(data[key], root + '.' + key);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (data !== null && typeof data !== 'undefined') {
                    formData.append(root, data);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function ignore(root){
        return Array.isArray(ignoreList)
            && ignoreList.some(function(x) { return x === root; });
    }

    appendFormData(obj, rootName);

    return formData;
}
```

Comment: The only answer supporting arrays, objects and files.

Comment: Hi, why do you add the File to the root? Is it possible to add it to child too?

Comment: @CedricArnould It might be a misunderstanding but the method is recursive so even if it's written `formData.append(root, data)`, it doesn't mean that it's added to the root.

Comment: I understand your answer, strangely when I get the result in the server, I have a unique Collection of Files and the data. But I can see in a File the name give the information to which child it s connected. Maybe the problem comes from .Net Core and how it manage upload files.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: i'm trying to use this but there is no usage example. the expected format of the ignoreList param would be pretty helpful.

Comment: There is a big difference between `photos[0][file]` and `photos[0].file`. In the case of `photos[0][file]`, `file` is a locally available variable that needs to be defined, and if that variable is a string (or number), that is used as the key for lookup. On the other hand, `photos[0].file` directly looks up the key `file` on `photos[0]`. That has nothing to do with browsers, it's just how the JavaScript syntax works.

Comment: `photos[0].file` and `photos[0]['file']` would be equivalent, but here the second example is obviously weird. `photos[0][file]` is dynamic, `photos[0].file` is static, `photos[0]['file']` is static with magic string.

Comment: some illustrations for this code (especially the parameters) would be very helpful.

Comment: @ThaJay That doesn't make sense. That's just a string, not code.

Answer (score 32):

Try JSON.stringify function as below

```
var postData = JSON.stringify(item);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("postData",postData );
```

Comment: This doesn't work with files.

Answer (score 14):

```js
function toFormData(o) {
  return Object.entries(o).reduce((d,e) => (d.append(...e),d), new FormData())
}

var object = {
  username: 'JohnDoe',
  file: new File(['foo'], 'foo.txt', {type: 'text/plain'})
}

fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: toFormData(object)
}).then(r => r.json()).then(console.log)
```

Comment: It's valid only if JSON is flatten to 1 level, otherwise the FormData would could use recursion.

Answer (score 10):

I had a scenario where nested JSON had to be serialised in a linear fashion while form data is constructed, since this is how server expects values. So, I wrote a small recursive function which translates the JSON which is like this:

```
{
   "orderPrice":"11",
   "cardNumber":"************1234",
   "id":"8796191359018",
   "accountHolderName":"Raj Pawan",
   "expiryMonth":"02",
   "expiryYear":"2019",
   "issueNumber":null,
   "billingAddress":{
      "city":"Wonderland",
      "code":"8796682911767",
      "firstname":"Raj Pawan",
      "lastname":"Gumdal",
      "line1":"Addr Line 1",
      "line2":null,
      "state":"US-AS",
      "region":{
         "isocode":"US-AS"
      },
      "zip":"76767-6776"
   }
}
```

Into something like this:

```
{
   "orderPrice":"11",
   "cardNumber":"************1234",
   "id":"8796191359018",
   "accountHolderName":"Raj Pawan",
   "expiryMonth":"02",
   "expiryYear":"2019",
   "issueNumber":null,
   "billingAddress.city":"Wonderland",
   "billingAddress.code":"8796682911767",
   "billingAddress.firstname":"Raj Pawan",
   "billingAddress.lastname":"Gumdal",
   "billingAddress.line1":"Addr Line 1",
   "billingAddress.line2":null,
   "billingAddress.state":"US-AS",
   "billingAddress.region.isocode":"US-AS",
   "billingAddress.zip":"76767-6776"
}
```

The server would accept form data which is in this converted format.

Here is the function:

```
function jsonToFormData (inJSON, inTestJSON, inFormData, parentKey) {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/22783314/260665
    // Raj: Converts any nested JSON to formData.
    var form_data = inFormData || new FormData();
    var testJSON = inTestJSON || {};
    for ( var key in inJSON ) {
        // 1. If it is a recursion, then key has to be constructed like "parent.child" where parent JSON contains a child JSON
        // 2. Perform append data only if the value for key is not a JSON, recurse otherwise!
        var constructedKey = key;
        if (parentKey) {
            constructedKey = parentKey + "." + key;
        }

        var value = inJSON[key];
        if (value && value.constructor === {}.constructor) {
            // This is a JSON, we now need to recurse!
            jsonToFormData (value, testJSON, form_data, constructedKey);
        } else {
            form_data.append(constructedKey, inJSON[key]);
            testJSON[constructedKey] = inJSON[key];
        }
    }
    return form_data;
}
```

Invocation:

```
        var testJSON = {};
        var form_data = jsonToFormData (jsonForPost, testJSON);
```

I am using testJSON just to see the converted results since I would not be able to extract the contents of form_data. AJAX post call:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: somePostURL,
            data: form_data,
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (e) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 10):

You can simply use:

```
formData.append('item', JSON.stringify(item));
```

Comment: This doesn't work with files. And this solution was already posted.

Answer (score 9):

### 2022 Update

**Axios now supports automatic serialization of an object to FormData**

Since version 0.27 Axios supports automatic object serialization to a FormData object if the request Content-Type header is set to multipart/form-data. [Read more](https://github.com/axios/axios#-automatic-serialization-to-formdata)

### Nested objects and files

Following solutions handles nested objects and arrays and files.

```
const buildFormData = (formData: FormData, data: FormVal, parentKey?: string) => {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        data.forEach((el) => {
            buildFormData(formData, el, parentKey)
        })

    } else if (typeof data === "object" && !(data instanceof File)) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
            buildFormData(formData, (data as FormDataNest)[key], parentKey ? `${parentKey}.${key}` : key)
        })

    } else {
        if (isNil(data)) {
            return
        }

        let value = typeof data === "boolean" || typeof data === "number" ? data.toString() : data
        formData.append(parentKey as string, value)
    }
}

export const getFormData = (data: Record<string, FormDataNest>) => {
    const formData = new FormData()

    buildFormData(formData, data)

    return formData
}
```

**Types**

```
type FormDataPrimitive = string | Blob | number | boolean

interface FormDataNest {
  [x: string]: FormVal
}

type FormVal = FormDataNest | FormDataPrimitive
```

Comment: I like the solution, but I'd recommend starting with `if (isNil(data)) return` because `typeof null === 'object'`.

Comment: wonderful solution, I'd recommend changing the Array part to:
```let obj: FormDataNest = {};
            obj[index] = el;
            buildFormData(formData, obj, parentKey)```
as you need to append the index too in the array, not flatten it instead.

Comment: better add `FileList` to the `FormDataPrimitive` types.
and change the `data` type in `getFormData` to `FromDataNest`

Comment: What is Axios? This thing I guess? https://axios-http.com/docs/intro Would be good to introduce it a bit in the answer since the question doesn't concern Axios.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a short and sweet solution using `Object.entries()` that will take care of even your nested objects.

```
// If this is the object you want to convert to FormData...
const item = {
    description: 'First item',
    price: 13,
    photo: File
};

const formData = new FormData();

Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    formData.append(key, value);
});

// At this point, you can then pass formData to your handler method
```

Read more about `Object.entries()` over here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: This doesn't work with nested objects

Comment: Contrary to the explicit claim, it does NOT "take care of nested objects".

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for a late answer, but I was struggling with this as Angular 2 currently does not support file upload. So, the way to do it was sending a `XMLHttpRequest` with `FormData`. So, I created a function to do it. I'm using **Typescript**. To convert it to **Javascript** just remove data types declaration.

```
/**
     * Transforms the json data into form data.
     *
     * Example:
     *
     * Input:
     * 
     * fd = new FormData();
     * dob = {
     *  name: 'phone',
     *  photos: ['myphoto.jpg', 'myotherphoto.png'],
     *  price: '615.99',
     *  color: {
     *      front: 'red',
     *      back: 'blue'
     *  },
     *  buttons: ['power', 'volup', 'voldown'],
     *  cameras: [{
     *      name: 'front',
     *      res: '5Mpx'
     *  },{
     *      name: 'back',
     *      res: '10Mpx'
     *  }]
     * };
     * Say we want to replace 'myotherphoto.png'. We'll have this 'fob'.
     * fob = {
     *  photos: [null, <File object>]
     * };
     * Say we want to wrap the object (Rails way):
     * p = 'product';
     *
     * Output:
     *
     * 'fd' object updated. Now it will have these key-values "<key>, <value>":
     *
     * product[name], phone
     * product[photos][], myphoto.jpg
     * product[photos][], <File object>
     * product[color][front], red
     * product[color][back], blue
     * product[buttons][], power
     * product[buttons][], volup
     * product[buttons][], voldown
     * product[cameras][][name], front
     * product[cameras][][res], 5Mpx
     * product[cameras][][name], back
     * product[cameras][][res], 10Mpx
     * 
     * @param {FormData}  fd  FormData object where items will be appended to.
     * @param {Object}    dob Data object where items will be read from.
     * @param {Object =   null} fob File object where items will override dob's.
     * @param {string =   ''} p Prefix. Useful for wrapping objects and necessary for internal use (as this is a recursive method).
     */
    append(fd: FormData, dob: Object, fob: Object = null, p: string = ''){
        let apnd = this.append;

        function isObj(dob, fob, p){
            if(typeof dob == "object"){
                if(!!dob && dob.constructor === Array){
                    p += '[]';
                    for(let i = 0; i < dob.length; i++){
                        let aux_fob = !!fob ? fob[i] : fob;
                        isObj(dob[i], aux_fob, p);
                    }
                } else {
                    apnd(fd, dob, fob, p);
                }
            } else {
                let value = !!fob ? fob : dob;
                fd.append(p, value);
            }
        }

        for(let prop in dob){
            let aux_p = p == '' ? prop : `${p}[${prop}]`;
            let aux_fob = !!fob ? fob[prop] : fob;
            isObj(dob[prop], aux_fob, aux_p);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must include array indexes instead of a `[]` for object properties inside a numeric array to stay intact

Answer (score 3):

Recursively

```js
const toFormData = (f => f(f))(h => f => f(x => h(h)(f)(x)))(f => fd => pk => d => {
  if (d instanceof Object) {
    Object.keys(d).forEach(k => {
      const v = d[k] === null ? '' : d[k] === true ? 1 : d[k] === false ? 0 : d[k]
      if (pk) k = `${pk}[${k}]`
      if (v instanceof Object && !(v instanceof Date) && !(v instanceof File)) {
        return f(fd)(k)(v)
      } else {
        fd.append(k, v)
      }
    })
  }
  return fd
})(new FormData())()

let data = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
  children: [
    { name: 'Max', age: 3 },
    { name: 'Madonna', age: 10 }
  ]
}
console.log('data', data)
document.getElementById("data").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', JSON.stringify(data))

let formData = toFormData(data)

for (let key of formData.keys()) {
  console.log(key, formData.getAll(key).join(','))
  document.getElementById("item").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${key} = ${formData.getAll(key).join(',')}</li>`)
}
```

```html
<p id="data"></p>
<ul id="item"></ul>
```

Comment: `const toFormData = (f => f(f))(h => f => f(x => h(h)(f)(x)))(f => fd => pk => d => {` jesus christ

Comment: @ThaJay looks like Lisp with all the IIFEs.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution that will handle nested arrays and objects. Somebody may find it useful**

```
             function add_form_data(form_data,key,item,arr){
                if(typeof(item)==='object' && item && item.constructor===Array){
                    for(var i=0;i<item.length;i++){
                        var item2=item[i];
                        var key2=key+'[' + i +']';
                        if(arr){
                            key2=key+'[' + key2 +']';
                        }
                        add_form_data(form_data,key2,item2,true);
                    }
                }else if(typeof(item)==='object' && item){
                    for ( var key2 in item ) {
                        var item2=item[key2];
                        if(arr){
                            key2=key+'[' + key2 +']';
                        }
                        add_form_data(form_data,key2,item2,arr);
                    }
                }else{
                    form_data.append(key,item);
                }
            }
```

> Usage

```
            var form_data = new FormData();
            
            add_form_data(form_data,null,json_data);// provide json_data here
             
            var string_url_data=new URLSearchParams(form_data).toString();// if query string is needed
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone doesn't want to write their own logic to do this, then there is a library
[object-to-formdata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata) which solves all the above problems i.e. file, nested objects, etc. and I tried it, it works perfectly fine here is the example

```js
import { serialize } from 'object-to-formdata';

    const dataObject = {
     name: "API testing",
     description: "This is to test the API",
     SubObject: {
       subObjectKey1: 3,
       subObjectKey2: 10
       },
     size: 1000,
     batch: 5
    }
    const formData = serialize(dataObject,{dotsForObjectNotation:true})
```

you can see the other options in the documentation.

```
const formData = serialize({ format: 'c', input: { file: new File([], 'foo.txt') } })
console.log(formData.get('format'), formData.get('input[file]'))
// c File { size: 0, type: '', name: 'foo.txt', lastModified: 1706061151530 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case my object also had property which was array of files. Since they are binary they should be dealt differently - index doesn't need to be part of the key. So i modified @Vladimir Novopashin's and  @developer033's answer:

```
export function convertToFormData(data, formData, parentKey) {
  if(data === null || data === undefined) return null;

  formData = formData || new FormData();

  if (typeof data === 'object' && !(data instanceof Date) && !(data instanceof File)) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => 
      convertToFormData(data[key], formData, (!parentKey ? key : (data[key] instanceof File ? parentKey : `${parentKey}[${key}]`)))
    );
  } else {
    formData.append(parentKey, data);
  }

  return formData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for this, a code that receive your javascript object, create a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object from it and then POST it to your server using new [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
    let myJsObj = {'someIndex': 'a value'};

    let datos = new FormData();
    for (let i in myJsObj){
        datos.append( i, myJsObj[i] );
    }

    fetch('your.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: datos
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(objson => {
            console.log('Success:', objson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This answer doesn't answer the question directly, it gives illustrations and alternatives instead.

People usually use `FormData` to allow them to upload files, there are 3 ways to do that, I'll mention them in detail in this answer.

**1. Get the data from the form directly**

To do so, you need to have the `name` and the `value` attributes in each input, then you tell the FormData to get the values from the form DOM;

```
let formData = new FormData(data.target as HTMLFormElement)
```

- Pros:

1. you don't need to involve a JS solution to get the values.
2. native support for nested data, arrays, etc ...

- cons:

1. you will need to make sure that all data needed are added as a value attribute on input DOMs

**2. Converting data by JS**
If you have the values stored in a variable then you can append them to the `FormData` using JS.

- Pros:

1. can be manipulated as needed
2. you don't need to have value attributes in input DOMs

- Cons:

1. custom complex JS to append nested data to the `FormData` object
2. you need to have the values stored in a variable

**3. Upload files in a separate request**

you can make a separate form for the file upload input.

- Pros:

1. you don't need to wait for uploads to submit
2. you don't need to worry about appending all your data to the `FormData` object, you will only append the files.

- Cons:

1. you need to handle these uploads in the backend before creating the entity itself
2. you need to handle deleting a file, both on front-end and back-end

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can do this simply by `$.param(obj)` .

Example:

```js
 const obj = {
   description: 'Some Item',
   price: '0.00',
   srate: '0.00',
   color: 'red'
}

const form_obj = $.param(obj);

$.ajax({
  url:"example.com",
  method:"POST",
  data:form_obj
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simplistic TypeScript implementation based on answers from @Vladimir Novopashin and @developer033.  [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgFC4BcBPAB1gAIBlWVAS2WloC9ZkAjOcgXl3L-IA%205CATpgA5r35CwAVwC2bGlL5C2IGKzArB5OdGg6hAEWQFYR8gDFacSwG9yAbQAeALmGjaE3XMU0AXQ9qOgZmVg4KAF9LAEFUVGQiAB4Q%20kYWdjgAPjxcADNZMGACWnBhGnTw9B0AEzNkYMqwzMiAGh0SNFgwAgBpWCJucgByEY7%20cnyQVHlTAkbrGbmG4bBYAHcl2fnkLFxMDytl3fJ7HVp88nRyYjIQK-qF7i4uUZExcRHMM51J6Z2DXgyBIZDAtXQXVQPX6gza5CeyBwOii5Fg0AgFEu11upFgDwRq1ebxGfiUqG%20v0m-xOQJBYIhUJhAyI8MR8AIIEoXgkWGRk1R6Mx5GxNzu%20MeRNeo3UmmQYEp52p-ABKwWwNBPUZ3V6LLZqwA-KNRLJYCNyB4RvkGJjvngBWiMViruhES83vpoD8lcqprT1fStZCdbDWaNPXaUY7haK3d4RPLgBLyPNYN6-ir-cgNQzg9DdXDCerOQBJSgAeW5nz59v4gqdIpdccgC2KyZscHTvr9gIDmvBeeZhcR-Lr0YoPuVAHop%20R4okiBByPLauQQGwAFawEoQDN8cub7cEeAwuiwCCuhqYeAAgCiyGAAAt0OhT0QPE4Pt5xL4FOT4WkLQRHAAQ-Fw2RUt2-CgC2zgANaFgAbgwpoBMMb61lBFShBksDoMh0CmvCTIFkMRoAAYACT2CRoZRE41EIUQUQBORFrkExHJcjy4hYPCqq7KOypREJ5AxDo0IELIqBgD2arIHg4kzspKkqfwAAqt6UOpJYAHIAOLkKpxkqfgMEiLc54EKcbyTsulrIOMOhsB4ABMEzQR41pOh5fC1B4nq%20VMHh2ZMtSwLAJCWusIiwLUTnduuW4lB4ACMrkAMwACwAKxBVEQXiB%20qVtO5GUBEFj4fnukFYfKIAEI%20NCWuFkUJVhehWXFlpJUe7XCToFUXAFmwpmYeGYEFG4jVsHZ4U4FWjPIRBzd8HRRHk5kEJZIjHL2yDDJiOHVOYIiCXg85JDeqAgPI6CnQQe3ySevRnhemDXneD7Pm%203AQeZmjwNAIC8W%20TgAAyLWDqWgTgQA)

```js
type Serializeable =
    | string
    | number
    | boolean
    | null
    | Date
    | File
    | { [x: string | number]: Serializeable }
    | Array<Serializeable>;

function serialize(
    data: Serializeable,
    parentKey = '',
    formData: FormData = new FormData()
): FormData {
    if ( typeof data === 'string') {
        formData.append(parentKey, data);
    } else if ( typeof data === 'number') {
        formData.append(parentKey, data.toString());
    } else if ( typeof data === 'boolean') {
        formData.append(parentKey, data ? 'true' : 'false');
    } else if (data === null) {
        formData.append(parentKey, 'null');
    } else if (data instanceof Date) {
        formData.append(parentKey, data.toISOString());
    } else if (data instanceof File) {
        formData.append(parentKey, data);
    } else {
        // Arrays and objects
        Object.entries(data).forEach((entry: [string | number, Serializeable]) => {
            const [key, value] = entry;
            serialize(value, parentKey ? `${parentKey}[${key}]` : key.toString(), formData);
        });
    }

    return formData;
}
```

Comment: `File` logic should include `Blob`

Answer (score 1):

This works for Arrays, nested objects, Dates, anything:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata

Just run `npm i object-to-formdata -- save`

```
const formData = serialize(object);
```

Do not implement it by yourself, apart from that, lot of answers are incomplete here, does not work for array eg.

Answer (score 0):

This method convert a JS object to a FormData :

```js
function convertToFormData(params) {
    return Object.entries(params)
        .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                value.forEach((v, k) => acc.append(`${key}[${k}]`, value));
            } else if (typeof value === 'object' && !(value instanceof File) && !(value instanceof Date)) {
                Object.entries(value).forEach((v, k) => acc.append(`${key}[${k}]`, value));
            } else {
                acc.append(key, value);
            }

            return acc;
        }, new FormData());
}
```

Comment: Just fix the iteration nested object entries call:

```Object.entries(value).forEach((v, k) => acc.append(`${key}[${v[0]}]`, v[1]));```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install `qs`:

```
npm i qs
```

Simply import:

```
import qs from 'qs'
```

Pass object to `qs.stringify()`:

```
var item = {
   description: 'Some Item',
   price : '0.00',
   srate : '0.00',
   color : 'red',
   ...
   ...
}

qs.stringify(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for Post my object data as Form Data.

```
const encodeData = require('querystring');

const object = {type: 'Authorization', username: 'test', password: '123456'};

console.log(object);
console.log(encodeData.stringify(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

I reference this from [Gudradain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49388446/6316227). I edit it a little in Typescript format.

```
class UtilityService {
    private appendFormData(formData, data, rootName) {

        let root = rootName || '';
        if (data instanceof File) {
            formData.append(root, data);
        } else if (Array.isArray(data)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                this.appendFormData(formData, data[i], root + '[' + i + ']');
            }
        } else if (typeof data === 'object' && data) {
            for (var key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    if (root === '') {
                        this.appendFormData(formData, data[key], key);
                    } else {
                        this.appendFormData(formData, data[key], root + '.' + key);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (data !== null && typeof data !== 'undefined') {
                formData.append(root, data);
            }
        }
    }

    getFormDataFromObj(data) {
        var formData = new FormData();

        this.appendFormData(formData, data, '');

        return formData;
    }
}

export let UtilityMan = new UtilityService();
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to the party but this is what I've created to convert a singular object to FormData.

```js
function formData(formData, filesIgnore = []) {
  let data = new FormData();

  let files = filesIgnore;

  Object.entries(formData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && !files.includes(key)) {
      data.append(key, JSON.stringify(value) || null);
    } else if (files.includes(key)) {
      data.append(key, value[0] || null);
    } else {
      data.append(key, value || null);
    }
  })

  return data;
}
```

How does it work?
It will convert and return all properties expect File objects that you've set in the ignore list (2nd argument. If anyone could tell me a better way to determine this that would help!) into a json string using `JSON.stringify`. Then on your server you'll just need to convert it back into a JSON object.

Example:

```js
let form = {
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Doe',
  details: {
    phone_number: 1234 5678 910,
    address: '123 Some Street',
  },
  profile_picture: [object FileList] // set by your form file input. Currently only support 1 file per property.
}

function submit() {
  let data = formData(form, ['profile_picture']);

  axios.post('/url', data).then(res => {
    console.log('object uploaded');
  })
}
```

I am still kinda new to Http requests and JavaScript so any feedback would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Simply this can be done :

```
var item: { some1: "ajbd" , some2: "dds".. }
let myFormData = new FormData();
      
       const abc = item.some1;
       const xyz = item.some2;

          myFormData.append('field1', abc);
          myFormData.append('field2', xyz);
    
    fetch('http:url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': false,
      },
      body: myFormData,
    }).
do promise ..
```

Comment: What happens if the `var item` changes, or if you don't know the `object` size?

Answer (score 0):

- Skip `null` and `undefined` values
- Handles `File` and `Array` types

```js
public static objectToFormData = (obj: any): FormData => {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    // Recursive function to handle nested objects
    const appendFormData = (data: any, path: string = ''): void => {
      if ([null, undefined].includes(data)) {
        return;
      }

      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        data.forEach((value: any, index: number) => {
          const newPath: string = `${path}[${index}]`;
          appendFormData(value, newPath);
        });
      } else if (data instanceof File) {
        formData.append(path, data);
      } else if (typeof data === 'object') {
        Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]: [string, any]) => {
          const newPath: string = path ? `${path}.${key}` : key;
          appendFormData(value, newPath);
        });
      } else {
        formData.append(path, String(data));
      }
    };

    appendFormData(obj);

    return formData;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me

```
const buildFormData = (formData: FormData, data: Record<string, any>, parentKey = ''): void => {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        data.forEach((item, index) => {
            const newKey = parentKey ? `${parentKey}[${index}]` : `${index}`;
            if (typeof item === 'object') {
                buildFormData(formData, item, newKey);
            } else {
                formData.append(newKey, item);
            }
        });
    } else {
        for (const key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                const newKey = parentKey ? `${parentKey}.${key}` : key;
                const value = data[key];

                if (typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number') {
                    formData.append(newKey, value.toString());
                } else if (value instanceof File) {
                    formData.append(newKey, value);
                } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
                    buildFormData(formData, value, newKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Try obj2fd => https://www.npmjs.com/package/obj2fd

```
import obj2fd from 'obj2fd'

let data = {a:1, b:2, c:{ca:1}};
let dataWithFormData = obj2fd(data);
//result => [a=>1, b=>2, c=>[ca=>1]]
```