# ERROR TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a FormData object from an html form

```
<form #basicForm ="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="basicFormSubmit(basicForm.value)">
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                            <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
                                   ngModel>



                            <label for="age">Age</label>
                            <input type="number" name="age" id="age" class="form-control"
                             ngModel>



                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit</button>                          
                    </form>
```

Angular method controlling the form submission

```
basicFormSubmit(data){
  let formdata= new FormData(data);  
  console.log(formdata);
  this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/testproject",formdata).subscribe();
  }
```

But I'm getting the following error `ERROR TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement`

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You want to create a form with this info `{name: '___', age: __}`? What exaclty are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @NicholasK Yes ,that's what I want to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783108/convert-js-object-to-form-data

Comment: Why not use a reactive form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method to convert the object to FromData

```
for (const key in data) {
    formdata.append(key, data[key]);
}
```

Comment: It worked. But do you have any idea why `let formdata= new FormData(data)` doesn't work?

Comment: You can only send in a HTMLFormElement to the FromData constructor. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)