# Convert object with nested arrays to FormData

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, form-data

I have this Object

```
{
  "Data1": 1,
  "Data2": "some string",
  "Data3": [
    {
      "ID": 0,
      "Name": "some name",
      "SomeArray": []
    },
    {
     "ID": 0,
     "Name": "another name",
     "SomeArray": [
       "DataA": 0,
       "DataB": "some data again"
     ]
    }],
  "Data4": "some string again"
}
```

The model which it will receive in the controller is this:

```
public class Data 
{
   public int Data1 { get; set; }
   public string Data2 { get; set; }
   public List<AnotherClass> Data3 { get; set; }
   public string Data4 { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<DataList> SomeArray { get; set; }
}

public class DataList
{
   public int DataA { get; set; }
   public string DataB { get; set; }
}
```

The data that is to be set in `Data3` is coming from a table where new inputs are retrieved from a modal popup and populated in the table. `SomeArray` data is coming from a dropdown which uses `Select2` tool to set multiple choices in a dropdown.

The idea is that once the user clicks "Save", it will get all of the data, including those in the table and form this JSON object. From this object, I want to convert it into a `FormData`. However when it iterates into `Data3`, it doesn't  convert it into an array of objects even if I stringify it. I've also tried this one [Convert JS Object to form data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42483509/440310) but was unsuccessful.

Here's what I did so far:

```
var details = GetDetails(); // This contains `Data1`, `Data2` and `Data4`
var data3 = GetData3FromTable(); // This contains the list of `Data3`

var result = new FormData();
for (var key in details) {
   result.append(key, details[key]);
}

result.append("Data3", JSON.stringify(data3));
result.append("UploadFile", $("#upload")[0].files[0]);

// do ajax put or post after this line
```

Is there any jquery or javascript plugin that I can use to convert this object into `FormData`? Or is there any other way to convert it into `FormData`?

Comment: How would the form look that produced such formdata? Also why not just send it as JSON, that is what the string format is for

Comment: This is just a section of the entire JSON object and data from Data3 is coming from a table. The reason why I am converting this object to FormData is because I will be adding a file uploader control here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link [object-to-form-data](https://gist.github.com/ghinda/8442a57f22099bdb2e34) where it converts any object, including nested arrays and upload files into `FormData`. However, there's just one change that needs to be done:

From the link, replace `objectToFormData(obj[property], fd, property);` with `objectToFormData(obj[property], fd, formKey);`. This way, it sets the original property as the key. The output of the `FormData` when it is passed to the controller will be this:

```
Data1: 1
Data2: some string
Data3[0][ID]: 0
Data3[0][Name]: some name
Data3[0][SomeArray]: []
Data3[1][ID]: 0
Data3[1][Name]: another name
Data3[1][SomeArray][0][DataA]: 0
Data3[1][SomeArray][0][DataB]: some data again
Data4: some string again
```

I hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

You can send deeply nested data in HTML forms, but I have noticed that different web servers may interpret the more complex structures differently, so you may need to check your framework/app's middleware to ensure proper decoding.  You may find it easier to read values into Javascript and send the data from there.

Your `Data3` object could be represented using something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="data[Data3][0][id]" value="0">
<input type="text" name="data[Data3][0][Name]" value="some name">
<input type="text" name="data[Data3][0][SomeArray][]" value="">
```

You need a "parent" field (`data` in this example) which houses the child elements.

Note that you have to be careful of any `[]` -- you may need to specify the array index manually as above, otherwise the "grouping" of values won't be respected.

Also beware of names ending with `[]`: those fields will still send values, even if it's an empty string, so you may need to filter those out.

Comment: The story of `Data3` is that this is coming from a table. What I did was that once I got the data from that table, I set it in `Data3` like so.

Comment: If this is coming from a database table, then you may want to consider using the primary key as the array index.  E.g. `data[Data3][123][Name]` for row 123.

Comment: Then how to cater for the new ones? Also the data entry for the new entries will be coming from a modal popup (all of them are dropdowns) and populated in the table. Then the `SomeArray` is using a `Select2` plugin. So I don't know how it fits in my issue.

Comment: If you need to code a form for a new record, I would keep the structure "shallow", e.g. use `<input name="foo">` and post that to an API route dedicated to creating new resources, e.g. `/api/users` -- there is seldom a need to post all the old data when creating a new resource, but if you have that need, perhaps you can elaborate more in your question to help us understand what you are needing to do.