# how to add authentication in nuxt.js content docs theme

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have created a NUXT.JS content static site served with .md files. Now i want to add authentication to it. I want to redirect a user form my main site which is built in VUE.JS

User have to login to my main site and then clicking on a link -> redirect the user to nuxt site

Here are my nuxt configs:

```
import theme from '@nuxt/content-theme-docs'

export default theme({
docs: {
primaryColor: '#E24F55'
},
content: {
liveEdit: false
},
buildModules: [
'@nuxtjs/color-mode'
],
colorMode: {
preference: '', // default value of $colorMode.preference
fallback: 'light', // fallback value if not system preference found
hid: 'nuxt-color-mode-script',
globalName: '__NUXT_COLOR_MODE__',
componentName: 'ColorScheme',
classPrefix: '',
classSuffix: '-mode',
storageKey: 'nuxt-color-mode'
},
})
```

-------->>>>>>>>

```
    In middleware>stats.js
    
    export default function ({ route, redirect }) {
    console.log('route', route)
    // api call to check further
   }




nuxt.config.js
   import theme from '@nuxt/content-theme-docs'

export default theme({
  docs: {
    primaryColor: '#E24F55'
  },
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios'],
  
  router: {
    middleware: 'stats'
  }
})
```

[image]

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question because we do not know what your authentication looks like. Basically, https://auth.nuxtjs.org/ is suitable for any kind of authentication.

Comment: I know this plugin but I don't have any vue file. I have just created static md files using @nuxt/docs theme and now I want to check if user is logged in to my site or not before serving the content

Comment: You can protect your `@nuxt/docs-theme` behind a `@nuxt/auth` middleware using Auth0 by targetting your app to serve an SPA only. Not sure about the other Vue site tho..

Comment: @kissu, Thanks for replying. Is there any example you can show me so that I can follow the steps

Comment: @nuxt/docs theme is nothing else than a nuxt application. You can also create middleware, plugins & components in it. You can then perform your authentication there.

Comment: @4ern It would be great if you can show me a working example because I'm very new to this.

Comment: I can share a repo I made for my girlfriend. Just gonna need to strip the private info and explain a bit the configuration of Auth0. Will probably share it today.

Comment: @kissu cool. It would be a great help thanks.

Comment: @kissu Yes, It did helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @4ern Your example helped me and I'm able to make it work Thanks a ton.
Do you know why axios in nuxt sending my object as a string if I'm passing the object in body?

Comment: This is normal with axios and other frameworks, that json strings are sent. What you probably want is a form dataset, as you are used to with php. You can find out exactly how this works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22783314/6725944)

Comment: So, internally axios must be using JSON.stringify is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh ok, you're right, he can't register the middleware.
But you can create a plugin with beforeEach.

```js
// plugins/guard.js

export default ({ app }) => {
    app.router.beforeEach((to,from, next) => {
        console.log(to, from)
        next()
    })
}
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js

// ...

plugins: [__dirname + '/plugins/guard.js'],

// ...
```

Comment: The middleware had to be in the nuxt.config.js file but okay..

Comment: no you cannot currently use middleware in docs-theme. https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/809

Answer (score 2):

Here is a local/jwt example of how to use nuxt-auth in @nuxt/docs theme.

The file structure:

```
├───components
│   └───global
         auth.vue
├───content
│   └───en
         playground.md
├───node_modules
├───nuxt.config
├───package.json
├───static
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js

import theme from "@nuxt/content-theme-docs";

export default theme({
  docs: {
    primaryColor: "#E24F55",
  },

  content: {
    liveEdit: false,
  },

  buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/color-mode"],

  colorMode: {
    preference: "", // default value of $colorMode.preference
    fallback: "light", // fallback value if not system preference found
    hid: "nuxt-color-mode-script",
    globalName: "__NUXT_COLOR_MODE__",
    componentName: "ColorScheme",
    classPrefix: "",
    classSuffix: "-mode",
    storageKey: "nuxt-color-mode",
  },

  // ---->
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: "token",
          // required: true,
          // type: 'Bearer'
        },
        user: {
          property: "user",
          // autoFetch: true
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: "/api/auth/login", method: "post" },
          logout: { url: "/api/auth/logout", method: "post" },
          user: { url: "/api/auth/user", method: "get" },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  // <----
});
```

```
// components/global/auth.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="userLogin">
      <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="login.username" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="login.password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      login: {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async userLogin() {
      try {
        let response = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: this.login })
        console.log(response)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and in your *.md file use the auth component:

```
---
title: Playground
description: ''
position: 1
category: Playground
---

<auth></auth>
```

This example is quite simple. It is only meant to show how to use nuxt auth in the nuxt docs theme.

Comment: Is there any way that before the page is served I can hit an api to check if user's is logged in or not (just like we have beforeEach Route hook in VUE JS)?
Note I dont want a log-in page in the nuxt project. User will be login in our vue project and from there on clicking a link he'll be redirected to the nuxt project(url)

Comment: In nuxt, the middleware serves as a beforeEach route. You can place your logic there.

Comment: I think middleware works on pages or group of pages and in my case it is .md files. So when trying to define a middleware It's throwing error: "Unknown middleware stats"

Comment: middleware is executed at the very beginning. can you show me how you implemented the middleware?

Comment: Hi, I have added the code in question.Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent some time redacting how to do it. Unfortunately I could not make proper edited and annotated screenshots of the Auth0 (too cumbersome with my current setup to make something clean) but here is my github repo with all the explanations on how to make this work.

https://github.com/kissu/so-nuxt-docs-theme-auth-auth0

Comment: I'm running it locally and everytime I'm trying to access the login page it's throwing error. Can you plz explain this?

Comment: Please be more explicit on the error/setup here. Did you follow every step in the readme ?