# How to use JSON Stringify to send form-data instead of application/json with JSON .stringify()?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, strapi

Hi I need to convert JSON to form-data or x-www-forum-urlencoded and I am unsure how to do this using JSON.stringify(). Would anyone be able to help me? I'm using react native and strapi headless CMS in order to try and get authentication set up for my application but I'm getting a bad request 400 error.

Code:

```
const auth = useMemo( () => ({
    login: async (email, password) => {
      const {data} = await axios.post('http://192.168.0.11:1337/auth/local', {
        identifer: email,
        password,
      });
```

[Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REEh4.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783108/convert-js-object-to-form-data, can find your solution here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JS Object to form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783108/convert-js-object-to-form-data)

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```js
const auth = useMemo(() => ({
    login: async (email, password) => {
      const bodyFormData = new FormData();
      bodyFormData.append('identifer', email);
      bodyFormData.append('password', password);

      const {data} = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://192.168.0.11:1337/auth/local',
        data: bodyFormData,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      });
```

Here's some more info: [axios post request to send form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working and I am still getting a 400 error.

Comment: What error are you getting on your backend?

Comment: On the strapi backend its saying "POST /auth/local (8ms) 400" meaning that the server couldnt take the request. I've checked all my code multiple times and can't see any errors. I was following a video on YouTube which was going well and I got the registration working fine a similar way but I keep getting an 400 error everytime I try login with valid credentials. I updated the post to show the error image I'm getting on VSCode frontend.