# Array of objects to form-data format Javascript

Tags: javascript, form-data

Im trying to deal with the next problem - convert array of objects to form-data format

```
const obj = [{ name: 'Sergio' , age: 16 } , { name: 'Ivan' , age: 24 }]
```

What is the best decision to handle this problem? Ive already tried cycle, but still give me incorrect answer

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your expected output with format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JS Object to form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783108/convert-js-object-to-form-data)

Comment: [Search your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=Array+of+objects+to+form-data+site:stackoverflow.com)