# How to remove string datatype in append array of multiple objects through form data in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, react-redux, react-state-management

I am integrating varientform.i have recieving array of object in state.but when im trying to submit data so im getting this kind of data in console

```
varientDetails: [
    '{"index":0.2731402713862625,"sort":"45","sku":"5","waightorquantity":"1","Unit":"","mrp":"","discount":"","price":"","stock":"","minstock":"","outofstock":""}'
  ]
```

im using this code......

```
varientDetails.forEach(varient =>{formData.append(`varientDetails[]`,JSON.stringify(varient))})
```

Comment: It's already stringified JSON

Comment: yes but  there is string cotes ' ' at the start and end point

Comment: that is creating issue,during submittion,

Comment: You can [convert your object into a FormData Object itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783108/convert-js-object-to-form-data), or parse the JSON string back into an object on the receiving end of the request.

Comment: still this is not working