# Iterate an Object and Append as FormData (Including files, and normal text)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to upload files using formData, but also I do have some other fields that I need to include in the formData, so because I have an long object I want a automatic loop that iterates through the object I have and fills the form data.

For example this is my object:

```
const data {
  name: 'Adrian',
  files: [many other file uploads],
  houses: ['Mansion Q', 'Small Tini Sini House :P']
}
```

And this is the data I need to stimulate:

```
const formData = new FormData();
// someway to formData.append('the key', 'value of the key')
```

Comment: [Convert JS Object to form data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22783108)

Answer (score -1):

This should help you

```js
const formData = new FormData();
Object.entries(data).forEach(entry => {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(value));
})
```

Comment: Sure let me check, also for example I have an array inside the value of the key and is showing as [object object] instead of the content ? What is the problem, also what about stringify should i do that wen i post form data?

Comment: Yes you should add only serialized (or primitive) data to a formData. I updated my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work with files.