# I am trying to send a image file to my backend server but when it arrives I receive an empty object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to make a form that takes an image sends it to the backend and saves it on my local disk but when I send my image file to the backend it displays an empty object.

Frontend

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

const Create_post = () => {

    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        let post = {
            file:data.image[0]
        }
        handleApi(post)
    }

    const handleApi = (post) => {

        console.log(post)

        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/post', post).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        })
    }

    return (  
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>      
                <input type='text'/>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <input type='file' name='fileInput' {...register(
                                'image', {required: true}
                            )}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type='submit' name='submitButton'/>      
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Create_post;
```

Backend

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const sql = require('mysql')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const imgUpload = require('express-fileupload')

const db = sql.createPool({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'password',
    database:'photo_website_database'
})

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(imgUpload())

app.post('/api/post/', (req, res)=>{
    let post = req.body
    console.log(post.file)
})

app.listen(3001,()=>{
    console.log('running on port 3001')  
})
```

...............................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a file, you have to send it as formData.

Convert your data into formData then send.

Also your content type should be multipart/form-data, but I think axios will add that header automatically for you when you give him formData

You can find online how to convert object into formData
[Convert JS Object to form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783108/convert-js-object-to-form-data)

Answer (score 0):

Files are sent through form data from frontend to backend
To post the FormData using `axios`, you need specify in header that you are sending `FormData`, for that `content-type` should be `multipart/form-data`.

Check this, how to use FormData with axios:

```
let formData = new FormData();    //formdata object

formData.append('name', 'ABC');   //append the values with key, value pair
formData.append('age', 20);

    const config = {     
        headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }

axios.post(url, formData, config)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

For uploading the images file you can follow this guide tutorial: [Upload files images in react using axios](https://www.bezkoder.com/react-file-upload-axios/)

And in the backend you can use the req.files to get the files not the req.body

```
app.post('/api/post/', (req, res)=>{
    let image = req.files;
    console.log("Image :", image);
})
```