# POSTed JSON object ending up with default values in API controller

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to POST some data to my web API using jQuery's AJAX function, but MVC doesn't serialise it successfully on the other end - it simply leaves the default values for the model. [Some seemingly useful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice) don't seem to solve my problem, and its not at all complicated, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

My model:

```
public class SavedLevel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

AJAX request:

```
var postData= {};
postData.ID = 12;
postData.Data = "hello";

$.ajax(
{
    url: "api/level/post",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({data : postData}),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data)
    {
        //Something
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        //Something
    }
});
```

The API controller.

```
[Route("api/level/post")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostLevel(SavedLevel data)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("id : " + data.ID);
    Debug.WriteLine("data : " + data.Data);

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The request body.

```
{"data":{"ID":12,"Data":"hello"}}
```

The `Debug` console outputs `0` and `""` instead of the expected `12` and `"hello"`.

Thanks for reading.

Note: I tried using a `dynamic` object and doesn't work at all - I can't even check if it's null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `data` to:

```
data: JSON.stringify(postData),
```

So the request body becomes:

```
{"ID":12,"Data":"hello"}
```

The C# is expecting the SavedLevel object, but you are sending the object wrapped in another object.

Comment: I think the saying "If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail" comes in well here. I guess I was confused by the other solution!! Thanks