# Simple JSON-String Query

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json

I am developing a web-app using AJAX requests on the client-side and Servlets on the server-side.

My aim is to send objects of Javascript to server, then do some manipulations there and send it back to show here.

Let's say my js object is

```
var obj={hero:"Spiderman",name:"Peter Parker"};
```

My Approach

1.Convert obj to JSON string and send

```
var str= JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp.open("POST",myurl,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json",true);
xmlhttp.send("data="+str);
```

2. Recieve string,convert this back to JSON, manipulate "name" to "Bruce Wayne" and send it back as string

3.Recieve and convert back to Json

```
var data= JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

I am struggling at second point.I am using org.json for it .I searched and read docs  but could not find satisfied answer for converting string to json and vica-versa in JAVA in my context.

It would be really helpful one could provide simple working code or point to some links where I can study.

P.S :

I cannot use Jquery as I am using AngularJS. [See Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

I will always send valid JSON string.

I can use other JSON lib. if its good than org.json and satisfy my needs.
Please provide its jar download link.

Comment: Try this [Jquery Ajax Posting json to webservice - Stackoverflow][1] I hope it may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice

Comment: Maybe [decoding json examples](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples) will help -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are able to pull out `data` in your server code

This is how you can do it using `org.json`:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject requestObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(data);
String name = (string)requestObj.get("name");
name = "Bruce Wayne";
```

Code to create the response can look something like this:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
response.put("name",name);
return response.toJSONString();
```

This assumes your server method returns a `String` type

And in case if you are using Servlet you can use `HttpServletResponse` object `res` to create response like:
`res.setContentType("application/json");
OutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
os.write(response.toString().getBytes());
os.close();`

Comment: Why would doing `name = "Bruce Wayne"` change the value? I'd expect that to change the value of `name` to a new String, but leave `requestObj`'s properties unchanged.

Comment: It won't change the original JSON object. This would be used inside the new JSON object that needs to be returned as String.

Comment: Why create a *new* JSON object, though? Just change the property in the one you've just created and then send it back.

Comment: That is up to the OP. The code should hopefully give an idea on how to work on step 2.

Comment: Thnx.Looking exactly for it. If you can please add some links for tutorials and How to send it back as a string :)

Comment: Not aware of any tutorials as such. This is something I have done at work. I am sure you can google for some very easily :)