# Server side session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, session

I want to set one value in server side session in client side and need to access that session in web service, so i tried below

In client side :

```
//Set the server side session like below  
 var vr_="demo.png";     
'<%Session["path"] = "' + vr_ + '"; %>';

//In alert,checked the server side session value like below
 alert('<%=Session["path"] %>');
```

the value getting in alert is fine and i called 
    the web service but when try to access the session in web service
        i am getting the following as session value

' + vr_ + ' not the original value "demo.png"

Please find the source code below,

In Javascript  :

```
  var vr_="G:\\13-06-15-demo\\app1\\uploads\\demo.png"
```

In Jquery ajax request, i called the webservice like below

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "../webservice/email.asmx/senmail",
        data: "{'tomail': '" + tomail + "','subject': '" + subject + "','message': '" + message + "','attachment': '" + vr_+ "'}",           
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

In web service, the method is like below

```
 public bool senmail(string toMailId, string subject, string message,string attachment)
    {
```

Comment: You cannot set session from client side, at all.

Comment: in that case,i need to send one image path to web service, so even tried to passed in parameters like these "G:\\13-06-15-demo\\app1\\uploads\\demo.png" but am getting unrecognised escape sewuence error

Comment: @NandhaKumar can you post he code you are using?

Comment: Try not doubling up the `\\`.

Comment: data shouldn't be quoted like this.

Comment: @fsacer it is in json format, i even tried like this var arg={mail:'',sub:''}

Comment: correct sorry missed it.

Comment: what's the error you are getting.

Comment: @fsacer unrecognisized escape sequence

Comment: where does it occur?

Comment: @fsacer in ajax request

Comment: try saving json string in another var and the output it using alert() to see if it is saved correctly.

Comment: also try again saving data as array and then generate JSON string using JSON.stringify like in this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice . I also think it makes code a whole lot more readable.

Comment: @fsacer in console i checked am getting this Object {toMailId: "nandha.manis@yahoo.in", subject: "1", attachment: "G:\13-06-15-demo\app1\uploads\demo.png", message: "1"}

Comment: @fsacer json.stringify works perfecltly thanks for your help

Comment: @NandhaKumar I updated my answer, so you can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a quotes problem, fix it like this:

```
<% Session["path"] = "'" + vr_ + "'"; %>
```

**EDIT 1:**
Javascript and ASP.NET are not the same, so you cannot access the variables, so you can't do it on the client side. You must send something to the server like a POST request using Javascript or easier using jQuery.

Here are some resources:

Using AJAX and Javascript:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

jQuery AJAX:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

**EDIT 2:**
The answer was to create a normal javascript object/array and then convert it to JSON using `JSON.stringify()`, like seen in this example:
[Jquery Ajax Posting json to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice).

`JSON.stringify()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: No in that i am getting vr_ does not exist in current context

Comment: Missed that javascript and ASP.NET are not the same, so you cannot access the variables, so you can't do it on the client side. You must send something to to the server like a post request using javascript or easier using jQuery.

Comment: can u see the comment i given to @john saunders and help me