# I get "Get" web service instead of "POST" web service

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, web-services, rest

I have used this post [Jquery Ajax Posting json to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice) to send data to the server via "POST" web service,but it has been traited like a "Get"
in "Network" section of the browser,this is what I get:

[image]

this is my code for the web service(ASP.net):

```
// Insert Student
        [Route("api/Students/ajout")]
        [System.Web.Http.ActionName("Create")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(Student value)
        {

            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _StudentService.Insert(value);
                    var response = Request.CreateResponse<Student>(HttpStatusCode.Created, value);
                    await _unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return response;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Model state is invalid");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

and this is my code (AngularJS)

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',    
       url : 'http://localhost:50001/api/Students/ajout',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: { FirstName: ''+$scope.FirstName+'', LastName: ''+ $scope.LastName+'' , Email: ''+ $scope.Email+'' , DropOut:'' +$scope.dropout.value1+'' , Live: ''+$scope.live.value2+'' , ClassId:2, ImageId:1}, // On fait passer nos variables, exactement comme en GET, au script more_com.php
       success: function(data){                             
            console.log("success");
       },
       failure: function(errMsg) {
        console.log(errMsg);
    }   
    });
```

have you please any idea how can I deal with this problem,thanks a lot for help

Update:
I have changed the code like that:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',    
       url : 'http://localhost:50001/api/Students/ajout',
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: { FirstName: ''+$scope.FirstName+'', LastName: ''+ $scope.LastName+'' , Email: ''+ $scope.Email+'' , DropOut:'' +$scope.dropout.value1+'' , Live: ''+$scope.live.value2+'' , ClassId:2, ImageId:1}, // On fait passer nos variables, exactement comme en GET, au script more_com.php
       success: function(data){

      $rootScope.usersData = angular.toJson(data);
       console.dir($rootScope.usersData);                                 
            console.log("success");
       },
       failure: function(errMsg) {
        console.log(errMsg);
    } });
```

but I get this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50001/api/Students/ajout. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: I believe you can't POST via jsonp

Comment: This is jquery code not angularjs

Comment: thanks mxa055 for your remarque I mean by angularJS that I put this request in a controller :D

Comment: If you need a post of get request in controller, use angularjs $http and than the angularjs tag will be appropriate, or if you leave it like that, remove angularjs cause it has nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your api try to remove [Route("api/Students/ajout")] and instead of [System.Web.Http.ActionName("Create")] put [HttpPost].
In your controller, I advise you to use angularjs queries rather than the ajax requests.

this request should run if you edit your api controller:

```
var request = $http({
    url:"api/students/",
    dataType:"json", 
    method:"POST",
    data:JSON.stringify(student),//you can send directly the object student if is well-trained or use params:{'name':value, ...}
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

And in your Api controller to recovered your object if you use JSON.stringify change your method for :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public void CreateStudent([FromBody]Student value)
    {
      ...
    }
```

I don't know if you do, but in your html instead of bind the property firstname on your input, bind student.firstName. Like this, you can recover directly $scope.student with the property $scope.student.firstName instead of recover each property one by one. And so send directly the object like I put in example.

So I hope this will helpfull. 
Keep me informed of your progress. Have nice day.

Comment: And on your api Controller Above the name of your class add '[Route("api/[controller]")]' like this in your request you no longer need to add the full url and just use " api / students".