# Jquery json error from ajax currency convert

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

Sorry for my bad english
i has purchase API form (xe.com) 799$/Y

so now i using currency convert json with jquery 
my code

```
$('#rate-from, #rate-to').on('change', function(){
                    var from = $('#rate-from').val(),
                        to   = $('#rate-to').val();
                    $.post( 'https://xecdapi.xe.com/v1/convert_from.json/?from=' + from + '&to=' + to + '&amount=1', function( data ) {

                        console.log(data);
                    }, "jsonp");


                });
```

The json response

```
{"terms":"http://www.xe.com/privacy.php","privacy":"http://www.xe.com/legal/dfs.php","from":"USD","amount":1.0,"timestamp":"2015-11-17T18:00:00Z","to":[{"quotecurrency":"VND","mid":22455.9171363339}]}
```

and in my chrome browser get error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :?from=USD&to=VND&amount=1&callback=jQuery111307792251328937709_1447864663039&_=1447864663040:1
```

Why can i work with this json

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to see another way to do this post, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice) for example, I holpe that can help you!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are making a POST request and trying to send the parameters/data in the URL(query string). Either change the type of request to a GET request using the query string(some work will probably be needed on the API side for this), or restructure your request as a POST with your values in the body ([relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request))