# Access value of an array sent to node/express server

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

Let me start by saying I am a total newbie/hack. The answer is probably very easy... I apologize in advance.

I am sending an object via jquery $.ajax (POST) to a Node.js server running express. The object looks something like this on my server before I make the Ajax call:

```
var data = {
  "to" : "someone@abc.com",
  "attachment" : [{"file": "somefile.jpg"}, {"file": "someOtherFile.jpg"}]
}
```

This is the call to my server:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://myHostHere.com",
    data: data,
    success: function(data){
      console.log("Success... Returned Data: " + data);
    }
});
```

On my Node server here is the route that accepts the request:

```
app.post('/send/', urlEncodeParser, function(req, res){
        console.log("Req Body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
      });
```

The `urlEncodeParser` middleware refers to this code:

```
let urlEncodeParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false });
```

My receiving Node server receives the object and I can easily get the value of "to" via req.body.to no problem... For some reason I can't figure out how to access the 'file' values though. When I `console.log` the `req.body` on my Node server I see now that my object looks different.

Specifically I call `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))`

The output to the console looks like this:

```
"to" : "some@abc.com",
"attachment[0][file]" : "somefile.jpg",
"attachment[1][file]" : "someOtherFile.jpg"
```

I cannot figure out how to access the value of `attachment[0][file]` in my code. I have tried `req.body.attachment[0].file` and `req.body.attachment[0][file]` and `req.body.attachment[0]['file']` each time I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Also I try to just `console.log("attachment: " + req.body.attachment)` and I get `attachment: undefined`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the middleware didn't parse it, so it's actually `req.body["attachment[1][file]"]` to access it

Comment: Thanks @adeneo that works... now to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value using the bracket notation:

```
req.body['attachment[0][file]']
```

More importantly though is that you find out why your request payload looks like that... Unfortunately you did not provide any information how you send the request...

Comment: I updated my original post with a little more information... Im thinking this has something to do with the middleware?

Comment: @Koreys - look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice?lq=1)