# How to catch data sent by Ajax using PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Would like to ask for a help. I'm having an issue about getting the right data that I wanted. Maybe there's something lack in my code. I always get null.

I didn't received any error on the console tab.

Here's my ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fsubmit").click(function() {    
   var emailval = $("#email").val().trim();
   
   $.ajax({
    url: '/test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'email='+emailval,
    success: function(data) { 
     console.log(data);
     return false;
    }
   });
  });
 });
```

Maybe you could help me fix the PHP. Still learning some stuff. Kindly put some details for lesson please.

Here's my PHP code

```
<?php 

    $date = new DateTime();
    $datelog = $date->format('d.m.Y h:i:s');
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    $message = '[' . $datelog . '] - email: ' . json_encode($data);

    echo($message);
?>
```

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not allowed to comment. Here's a little edit to Mohammad's answer. `isset()` returns true for blank form fields. Use `empty()` instead.

this runs in my system ..

ajax call

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(".fsubmit").click(function() {  
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("whooowww");
            var emailval = $("#email").val().trim();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/arrayfilter.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'email='+emailval,
                success: function(data) {   
                    console.log(data);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

html form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="user-input" id="email"/>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

php

```
if($_POST){
    if(!empty($_POST['email']))
        echo "$_POST[email]";
    }
}
```

Comment: the output became null again. hmm

Comment: is fsubmit a <button> or <input type='submit' />  ?

Comment: <button type="submit" class="fsubmit myButton">Submit</button>

Comment: i am assuming email in in a form ? if so

add e.preventDefault() to your click event handler

$('.fsumbit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //rest of the code
}

Comment: the button is not functioning anymore when I added e.preventDefault(). Also I didn't see any error in the console tab.

Comment: i copied your code and implemented it in my system and works.

let me edit my answer and give all of the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134958/discussion-between-sujan-basnet-and-kobe-bryan).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fsubmit").click(function() {    
        var emailval = $("#email").val().trim();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {email:emailval},
            success: function(data) {   
                console.log(data);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

then in php:

```
<?php 

    $date = new DateTime();
    $datelog = $date->format('d.m.Y h:i:s');
    $data = isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:'';

    $message = '[' . $datelog . '] - email: ' . json_encode($data);

    echo($message);
?>
```

You should always check for the posted elements if its `isset` or not.

Comment: still didn't received by PHP. The output null became a blank.

Comment: @KobeBryan try to var_dump the post request `var_dump($_POST)` and share us the output

Comment: is this what you meant? $data = var_dump($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:''; ?

Comment: this is the output: NULL [06.02.2017 10:20:08] - email: ""

Comment: @KobeBryan No, just type `var_dump($_POST);` alone

Comment: here's the output array(0) { } [06.02.2017 10:26:01] - email: null. What does it mean?

Comment: @KobeBryan there is nothing posted to your php page, please check your network activity in the browser "inspect element -> network tab" then filter the "XHR", do you see your request? what are the parameters handled within it ?

Comment: i've seen all my test.php activities.

Answer (score 0):

## The JS

I can see - at least - one major flaw in your JS code. You are passing `data: 'email='+emailval` to the request. This would be fine (well - possibly not, since you are not URL-encoding your message) for a GET, but with the post I'd doubt, that jQuery can make some decent JSON out of `email=Some arbitrary text`. At least it will make your JS vulnerable to injections. There are answers on how to send JSON to a webservice with jQuery, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice).

## The PHP

`$_POST['data']` (if this is correct) will contain a *string*. But according to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

> json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value

I don't think that this is what you want to do. You have a string, and you'll probably want to get an object from your JSON string (actually at the moment, I doubt that it's really a JSON string what you are passing). You can achieve this with `json_decode`, which

> json_decode — Decodes a JSON string

I'd suggest the following PHP code, which decodes the JSON into an array and then outputs the value of email

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

$message = '[' . $datelog . '] - email: ' . $data["email"];
```

For this to work, `$_POST['data']` will have to look like this

```
{'email': 'Your message'}
```

or the like.