# how to send parameter with ajax from loop data array

Tags: javascript, ajax

how to send parameter? `[{'b':0,'c':1,'d':2},{'b':1,'c':2,'d':3},{'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}]`

```
var a=[x,y,z];
for(i = 0; i < a; i++){
    var b = i;
    var c = i+1;
    var d = i+2;
};

$.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url: "http://192.168.34.211:8081/save",
      dataType: "json",
      data: .... ?   //[{'b':0,'c':1,'d':2},{'b':1,'c':2,'d':3},{'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}]
      success: function( data ) {

      }
 });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should probably turn it into a string with `JSON.stringify` or alike

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Ajax Posting json to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with JSON.stringify

```
var a=[x,y,z];
for(i = 0; i < a; i++){
    var b = i;
    var c = i+1;
    var d = i+2;
};

$.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url: "http://192.168.34.211:8081/save",
      contentType: 'application/json'
      data: JSON.stringify(postData)   //[{'b':0,'c':1,'d':2},{'b':1,'c':2,'d':3},{'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}]
      success: function( data ) {

      }
 });
```

I hope this will helps you.