# Nothing's in $_POST. Is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am fairly new to JavaScript and PHP, and it's the first time to encounter and use JSON. I think my AJAX request is fine, but even so, the `$_POST` array is empty.

Here is the AJAX call:

```
$( "#submit" ).click( function() {
    var submit_basic = $.post( 'index.php/submit_data/pass_basic_data',
                                get_experience_data()
                             );
    submit_basic.done( function(data) {
       alert(data);  // for debugging purposes
    });
});
```

And this is the function that takes the data from a table:

```
function get_experience_data() {

    var temp, data_exp = [];
    $( "#exptable tbody tr" ).each( function() {

        temp = {
            company: $(this).find('td').eq(0).html(),
            position: $(this).find('td').eq(1).html(),
            datestart: $(this).find('td').eq(2).html(),
            dateend: $(this).find('td').eq(3).html(),
            description: $(this).find('td').eq(4).html()
        };

        data_exp = data_exp.concat(temp);

     });

     return data_exp;
}
```

And for reference, the destination controller function that only prints the `$_POST` array (by the way I am using CodeIgniter):

```
public function pass_basic_data() {
    var_dump($_POST);        
}
```

Can you please pinpoint the error I've made, since I can't find it. Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:** I am getting this message in particular:

```
array(1) {
  ["undefined"] =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for all the help guys! I already solved it. It made me dance all around the room. 
I wrapped the return value in a `{name : value}` pair.

```
$( "#submit" ).click( function() {
    var post_vars = get_experience_data();
    var submit_basic = $.post( 'index.php/submit_data/pass_basic_data',
                                {object: post_vars}
                             );
    submit_basic.done( function(data) { 
       alert(data);  // for debugging purposes
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't think that `get_experience_data()` will wait until all the `.each()` callbacks complete before returning.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to .each()?

Comment: Don't worry, `$.each` is blocking - it will wait for it to complete.

Comment: i think this would be much simpler: `var submit_basic = $.post( 'index.php/submit_data/pass_basic_data', $("#exptable").serialize() );` ...and you dont even need the extra function

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the following for a start :

```
var submit_basic = $.post('index.php/submit_data/pass_basic_data', get_experience_data());
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, that was a typo, but still I am getting this error which makes me think that the $_POST is empty: 
array(1) {
  ["undefined"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Comment: You're actually sending 'undefined' to the server because your function call to get_experience_data() is failing (or the result is undef).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var submit_basic = $.post('index.php/submit_data/pass_basic_data', get_experience_data());
// you need to add parentheses here --------------------------------------------------^
```

When you pass a function to `$.post()` it assumes it is a callback that is to be called after the response is received. What you want to do is call the function and pass it's return value in to `$.post()`.

By the way, this line:

```
data_exp = data_exp.concat(temp);
```

could be replaced with:

```
data_exp.push(temp);
```

No need to be creating a new array every time if you're just adding a value to the end.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. That was a typo. Still $_POST is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the method get_experience_data, otherwise you are passing the function not executing it

Answer (score 0):

try troubleshooting the actual jquery, not the php part.
but heres a suggestion:

```
var post_vars = get_experience_data();
var submit_basic = $.post( 'index.php/submit_data/pass_basic_data', post_vars );
```

Comment: Tried it, still the same result.

Comment: you could try to console log the variable passed to the query as submitting it.. so before `return data_exp;` add `console.log(data_exp);` and see if the variable is passed on correctly.

Comment: also, you could try defining the data type `var submit_basic = $.post('index.php/submit_data/pass_basic_data', get_experience_data(), "json");`

Comment: ..however, i think that is only for the returned data. but this page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ shows that variables your pass on in the query should be either PlainObject or String type

Comment: I can see the objects in the console.

Comment: here is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/y37ve/ the way you set up your array is not a plain object

Comment: the {} brackets wont just work in the ajax, however, here's a topic you could cheek out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json

Comment: How do I set up the array as a plain object?

Answer (score 0):

here is a conclusion to my previous answer plus the comments, but im still not sure if you could stingify arrays in arrays..

```
var submit_basic = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'index.php/submit_data/pass_basic_data',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(get_experience_data()),
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**
modify your get_experience_data function according to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y37ve/1/) script

like this:

```
temp = '{ ';
temp+= '"company":"'  +$(this).find('td').eq(0).html()+  '", ';
temp+= '"position":"'  +$(this).find('td').eq(1).html()+  '", ';
temp+= '"datestart":"'  +$(this).find('td').eq(2).html()+  '", ';
temp+= '"dateend":"'  +$(this).find('td').eq(3).html()+  '", ';
temp+= '"description":"'  +$(this).find('td').eq(4).html()+  '"';
temp+= ' }';
```

Comment: This gets me a JSON Parse Error.