# Pass json data to the server in the header

Tags: json, jquery

```
function userCanLogin(credentials) {
  return $.getJSON(root + '/json/reply/authentication', credentials);
            }
```

The url created is this:

```
www.mydomain.com/?username=test&password=test
```

I want that these json credentials are passed to the header.

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have now?

Comment: that the url data like username and password is visible in the url bar

Comment: @Elisa Then use POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to POST data, not GET, as you are sending to the server. Second, try searching before posting the question, here is what you need:
[jQuery Posting JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json)

Comment: I asked for json header not how to do an ajax post. GET works in my case. Of course when I use json header I have to use ajax post because getJSON does not offer that functionality.

Comment: Using the header is a POST request.

Comment: @Elisa why do you want to do a GET instead of POST? Doesn't make sense for me, just want to be clear if there is a particular reason, otherwise you should really be using POST.

Comment: getJSON is a one-liner. $.ajax not. Technically GET works but is not what my colleague semantically wanted :)