# Post data being clipped

Tags: python, post, cgi

When sending a post request to a python CGI server via jquery, sometimes some of the arguments are clipped. When sending the same post request again the request is received in with complete data.

I have checked the chrome browser network requests and they show that request is being fully sent.

Here is an example of a partially sent request:

```
var message = {
    "to": "test.user@gmail.com",
    "sender": "test.user@gmail.com",
    "code": "K96nhC4qnIvzcM3XzaIMwfwuRjBooyHZWwtM1hIE\n2rD2WuvZ4B3/2J0xfDstsj91B/K8i7V6gjx1l/Mm\nX5skxuy6ih63ChZN3IWZjIXDCZ1F3V15/7oYDlsa\n6rgueyzEuW87nQJAmAh2P7tFEC6SQxEu/rln8DNs\nMrGSQRdMRY2kmzyVlnKbWEuZ6yjJes7TKaQ2GhL7\nSvAP4DMRl1mKSwnA7qAaCHVqG9iCPqyjy2eKJN/C\nviF7kBavfAZqcMlyY76VyMVSg3zG7t1LUfUA"
}
```

And the same request fully sent:

```
var message = {
    "to": "test.user@gmail.com",
    "sender": "test.user@gmail.com",
    "code": "K96nhC4qnIvzcM3XzaIMwfwuRjBooyHZWwtM1hIE\n2rD2WuvZ4B3/2J0xfDstsj91B/K8i7V6gjx1l/Mm\nX5skxuy6ih63ChZN3IWZjIXDCZ1F3V15/7oYDlsa\n6rgueyzEuW87nQJAmAh2P7tFEC6SQxEu/rln8DNs\nMrGSQRdMRY2kmzyVlnKbWEuZ6yjJes7TKaQ2GhL7\nSvAP4DMRl1mKSwnA7qAaCHVqG9iCPqyjy2eKJN/C\nviF7kBavfAZqcMlyY76VyMVSg3zG7t1LUfUAhsMN\nXWSoVzG/kmKJen3czBo74UT8s0eUXCtFa01Hfecv\nGbQVBHHlTCrz3y5IoOqUQQDHtzE5oke7TL46nv52\nhwr1Q0/Sc9+QXA+rd/iMOWKjEY+AfbizI5K6v4VJ\nlP6wEL1Wo49f5haAukgJ6kWjx4hI8dcwEKrM5kbR\nDqQ3nQuIAnYM+8NeMmfjgoS4ReovtjQPjN/dk+eP\nEGiF8XWkIHHuerORq/9PERxeitJcZEWWYSkmjPu9\n8mW4K3jSm0SG3LV+E6mOx3uycCYkh9O1mqfwBk+3\nEE8litsIJ84ivZ+FzPZsbI0u9w3zsKE="
}
```

Both examples are JSON formatted from server logs.

Here is the javascript:

```
$.post('cgi-bin/somescript.py', message, someCallback, 'text')
```

Comment: Can u show example of what you call full and clipped? Have you try to sniff with wireshark to make sure everything is sent.

Comment: can you show your jquery code?

Comment: @BorisIvanov Checking wireshark shows that the entire request is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'data' should be a stringified Javascript object:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "userName": userName, "password" : password })
```

Or, to send the data from the form, pass it formData, like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify(formData)
```

There's also a more detailed answer to a similar question here: [Jquery Ajax Posting json to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice)
[orginal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json)

Comment: I have tried this before, but I still get the clipping issue.