# GAE self.request.get() does not receive dict from POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I tried to send from web page

```
postdata= "{'key': 1}"
$.ajax('/admin/page', {
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
   'postdata': postdata
},
```

and receive that in GAE and try to populate ndb entry with postdata

```
postdata= self.request.get('postdata')
entry = DB_Class()
entry.populate(**postdata)
entry.put()
```

Populate doesn't work but results:  TypeError: _populate() argument after ** must be a mapping, not unicode

Am I doing something wrong in Ajax/post side or in GAE side?

But if I 'hardcode' dict in Python

```
postdata= {'key': 1}
entry = DB_Class()
entry.populate(**postdata)
entry.put()
```

that works perfectly.

Could you please advise what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that self.request.get('postdata') returns a string as it's being posted as url-encoded data. You need to:

```
import json
postdata_str = self.request.get('postdata') 
postdata = json.loads(postdata_str)
```

... if you want to take this approach. You should also consider if you want to post apparently flat data as JSON, when the basic url-encoded will work:

```
$.ajax('/admin/page', {
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
     'key': 1,
     'foo': 'bar',
   });
```

with:

```
key_str = self.request.get('key') 
key = int(key_str)
foo = self.request.get('foo')
```

Also see [jQuery posting JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json) for more info, but remember that webapp will still treat the data as a string.

Comment: Simple as that. Link to JQuery porting JSON was also very helpful. Thanks a lot Nick.