# How can I post json values to a server API?

Tags: javascript, json

I been trying to post json values to an API, with the code bellow.
Maybe I should use another approach to send/post json values to an API.
Couls somebody give me a hint? 
I wanna be able to post a new username and password to the API (username=bruno&password=login), how is it possible to do that?
Can I do It only using javascript?

```
var url = "http://192.168.8.143/api/v11/login/";
var parameters = "username=bruno&password=login";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters .length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Handler function for call back on state change.
    if(http.readyState == 4) {

        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(parameters);
```

Comment: stackoverflow-user Exception : http is undefined, please make an ajax call

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery posting JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json)

Comment: @johnSmith Ok, do you mean I should do it with a ajax call? Can you give me a hint, on how to do it?

Comment: You didn't created your request: `var http = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: @Tommi Hi, know its a warning and a error: <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in <b>/var/www/html/api/v11/Json.php(34) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>1</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/var/www/html/api/v11/Json.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />

Comment: It's a response from server side − error in php code.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be java? PHP can do it nicely ( in my opinion ) also if it is a third party api they probably have documentation on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
var parameters = '"username="+bruno+"&password="+login+"';
```

This is something that I can help.

Comment: Ok, I used your line of code, but know i get this error and warning: Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length" plan.dev/:1
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" plan.dev/:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)