# Serializing array with jquery in Rails friendly way

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to send a javascript array to a rails application using jquery

```
$.ajax
  url: 'some url'
  data: {list: [{id: 4, name: 'John'}, {id: 5, name: 'Locke'}]}
  method: 'post'
  dataType: 'json'
```

The problem with this method is that it serialize as follows:

list[0][id]=4&list[0][name]=John&... so on

Leading, on the Rails side to something like

```
    {"list"=>
      {
        "0"=>{"id"=>"4", "name"=>"John"},
        "1"=>{"id"=>"5", "name"=>"Locke"}
      }
     }
```

While I'd like to get something like

```
      {"list"=>
        [
          {"id"=>"4", "name"=>"John"},
          {"id"=>"5", "name"=>"Locke"}
        ]
       }
```

( Notice the inner list instead of a inner hash )

Is there a clean pretty way to send the data in a way rails would recognize it?

(PS: The view was not generated by rails, it is a phonegap mobile app)

This question [jQuery posting JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json) has little to do with my problem.

My problem is to serialize in a particular way, while the question is about how to serialize at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery posting JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json)

Comment: Convert the data to json with `JSON.stringify(obj)`. All modern clients (and IE8) support it natively.

Comment: Now jQuery interprets "data" as a single string, as the Rails server.

Comment: JSON.stringify(obj) may not be answer!

Comment: Yes, data is a single string according to both the server and jQuery; make sure the rails server knows that the content type is json (either using content type headers or format: :json or appending .json to the link)

Answer (score 2):

I see two options for you:

One, as others have suggested, use `JSON.stringify()` / `JSON.generate()` in your AJAX call. Yes, Rails will get your data as a single string, but that's okay. Use `JSON.parse()` once you receive the data to turn it back into JSON.

Two, just iterate through it anyway:

```
h = {"list"=>
      {
        "0"=>{"id"=>"4", "name"=>"John"},
        "1"=>{"id"=>"5", "name"=>"Locke"}
      }
     }

h['list'].each do |elem|
  value = elem[1]
end

# => {"id"=>"4", "name"=>"John"}
# => {"id"=>"5", "name"=>"Locke"}
```

Upon each iteration, `value` will be each element in your original array.