# Why does jackson convert ZonedDateTime to decimal?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, zoneddatetime

I am trying to understand why does Jackson transform ZonedDateTime to Decimal while getting MvcResult in a spring intergration Test ?

Here is the expected date : 2019-10-01T10:10:44+02:00[Europe/Paris]
and the actual result : 1572426644.000000000

Comment: Because `ZoneDateTime` is an timestamp.

Comment: Which conversion had you expected or wanted instead?

Comment: Try to register `JavaTimeModule` module. Take a look at: [Spring Boot Jackson date and timestamp Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256567/spring-boot-jackson-date-and-timestamp-format/55270120#55270120), [Umarshalling MonthDay spring jackson json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180301/umarshalling-monthday-spring-jackson-json), [Problem with deserialization of LocalDateTime in Junit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107588/problem-with-deserialization-of-localdatetime-in-junit-test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you use Spring Boot**, you can solve it in a more general way with the following property:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
```

This way you don't need to specify a JsonFormat for each date field you have.

If you also want to customize the date format globally, use the property:

```
spring.jackson.date-format
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: I will try this solution ASAP :) and give you my feedback

Comment: Nice! :) So you have three possible solutions here as answers. Can you accept one of them, please?

Comment: This solution doesn't work with the most recent version of spring.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer that gives a precise solution to your question: [Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for JSON serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627992/spring-data-jpa-zoneddatetime-format-for-json-serialization). In short, you need to annotate your ZonedDateTime as follows.

```
ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.now();

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
public ZonedDateTime getTime() {
    return time;
}
```

You also might need to add the dependency for JSR-310

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prevented the conversion by injecting `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in the Integration Test

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController).setMessageConverters(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter).build();
```