# Error parsing a JSON object with Instant type parse error

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a JSON Object with Instant type woth the value `2019-10-17T15:10:33.639Z`

but when I parse it I have this error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected one of [VALUE_STRING, VALUE_NUMBER_INT, VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT] for java.time.Instant value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected one of [VALUE_STRING, VALUE_NUMBER_INT, VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT] for java.time.Instant value
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 28] (through reference chain: com.bendiciones.buenas.noches.Bendiciones["estimatedResolutionDate"])
```

Comment: you need to show the code

Comment: Also add `request body`

Comment: Seems that you give an object like `{"date": "2019-10-17T15:10:33.639Z"}` while your code expects only a string `"2019-10-17T15:10:33.639Z"`.

Comment: Try to register `JavaTimeModule` module. Take a look at: [Spring Boot Jackson date and timestamp Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256567/spring-boot-jackson-date-and-timestamp-format/55270120#55270120), [Umarshalling MonthDay spring jackson json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180301/umarshalling-monthday-spring-jackson-json), [Problem with deserialization of LocalDateTime in Junit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107588/problem-with-deserialization-of-localdatetime-in-junit-test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [@JsonFormat](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) on your Instant property, about read more about JsonFormat [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat), do something like below

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
 private Instant currentdDate;
```