# AJAX send post request REST API (Provisional headers are shown)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, rest

I'm trying to send `post request data` to my `api`.

The `api` works fine in my postman,

But in my laravel project, I'm getting the `caution` like this

**Provisional headers are shown**

[image]

API to Send Post Request Data

`url: https://api.mydomain.com/api/login`

`{ "companyID":"2018-101", "password":"123456" }`

`Content-Type : application/json`

`Accept : application/json`

In my Laravel project here's my `ajax` that performs the sending of `post` data to the `api`.

```
$.ajax({
      headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
      url: "https://api.mydomain.com/api/login",
      method: "POST",
      data:{
           companyID:"2018-101",
           password:"123456"
      }, 
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(data)
      {
           alert("Successfully Login!");
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
      }
});
```

Here's my `Cors.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *a
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */

 public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    return $next($request)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',' Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',' true');
    }
   }
```

My Kernel.php

`\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,`

**UPDATED**

Tried to change the

`data:{
companyID:"2018-101",
password:"123456"
},`

to

`data: JSON.stringify({ "companyID": "2018-101", "password" : "123456" }),`

`contentType: "application/json",`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried in different browser? Could be some extension blocking it.

Comment: For starters, your _"API to Send Post Request Data"_ part shows the request payload as JSON but your jQuery code is sending an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request body. What format are you posting with Postman?

Comment: Im using application/json format when sending a request in my postman this is my sample json format that I'm sending to my postman `{ "companyID":"2018-101", "password":"123456" }`

Comment: Does this help ~ [jQuery posting JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json)?

Comment: What is the actual error? Nothing in this question shows an error message. What is the response from the request?

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ "companyID": "2018-101", "password" : "123456" })` this is what I tried to your link. But I'm getting `Unexpected Identifier` in my `success:function(data)`

Comment: I don't get any error except the caution shown to me `Provisional headers are shown` when I try to bring back the codes of `data:{
                                            companyID:"2018-101",
                                            password:"123456"
                                        }, `

Comment: Please [update the code in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57551619/edit) to match what you currently have. Please also include any error messages reported **in full**, including the location within your scripts that caused the error. Take a screenshot of your browser console if you think it will help

Comment: Post updated...

Comment: Did you add the correct `contentType` as per the [linked StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13204514/283366)?

Comment: Is that necessary? I have the Cors.php. Where can I place the `contentType` ?

Comment: Yes, see the answer I linked in the comment

Comment: Check the updated post

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},`

```
 $.ajax({
       url: "https://api.mydomain.com/api/login",
       method: "POST",
       data:{ companyID:"2018-101", password:"123456" }, 
       dataType: "json",
       success:function(data)
       {
            alert(data.data.access_token);
       },
       error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
       }
       });
```