# How can i pass Multiple Parameters to jQuery ajax call with datatype HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have the following jquery code to call a POST method in Asp.net core Controller

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetItemsForRelease", "PointOfSales")',
            data: { requestModel: TFObj },
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (responsedata) {
                $("#releaseItemsPush").html(responsedata);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

but following controller action shows null object

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetItemsForRelease(RequestModel requestModel)
{
  return PartialView("_partialReleaseItem", requestModel);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery posting JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570747/jquery-posting-json)

Comment: no, sorry iedited question again, controller action "requestModel" object always shows null

Comment: You don't appear to be applying the solutions listed in the other post so it still looks like a duplicate

Comment: Get rid of `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` which causing null data in your controller.

Comment: Share either `TFObj` or `requestModel` details so that your issue can be investigated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Following controller action shows null object

Well, as per your shared code snippet `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8` casuing null data on your controller it because you have define `dataType` as `html` but `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`. When we send `html` as `dataType` it would treat as `text` here in controller thus posted data has lost due to mismatched data type.

Let's assume you have following model:

Model:

```
public class RequestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Ajax:

```
            var TFObj = {};
            TFObj.Id = 1; // You can get HTML as $('#Id').val()
            TFObj.Name = "Test Name";
            TFObj.Email = "Test Email";
            console.log(TFObj);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/PointOfSales/GetItemsForRelease",
                type: "POST",
                data: { requestModel: TFObj },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (responsedata) {
                    $("#releaseItemsPush").html(responsedata);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

**Note:** Make sure, you data has been posted accordingly from  your browser, by checking console as following:

[image]

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetItemsForRelease(RequestModel requestModel)
        {
            return PartialView("_partialReleaseItem", requestModel);
        }
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can see we are getting data in controller. So just get rid of your `contentType` would resolve your null data.