# Cross-(sub)domain AJAX POST request (with file/large body)

Tags: javascript, post, iframe, cross-domain, subdomain

I need a script to perform a **POST** request to a different sub-domain than the one the page loads from, e.g. load data from `domain.com` and perform the AJAX **POST** to `post.domain.com`.

I've read about some alternatives that work for mainly for **GET** or **POST** with simple form data, but in this case I'll be posting a file (can be quite large).

I control the server, and both the page and the target are under the same domain. Is there any way to do this with JS/Iframes or do I have to resort to Flash/Flex?

As a side question, does `mod_proxy` for apache redirect a **POST** when the HTTP request is fully read (at apache) or it starts redirecting traffic (like a TCP tunnel) as soon as the headers are read?

Comment: This is an absurdly difficult thing to do. `curl` is fine. The server responds with a 201. I feel like I'm being "protected" into submission. I _want_ anyone to be able to post from anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/jquery-why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-insted-of-a-get-request) can help you.

Comment: This is exactly it; implemented the OPTIONS response at server side and it's working like a charm! With no ugly hacks :D

Answer (score 1):

For requesting data from another subdomain you could look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

For posting files you can definitely use iframes.

This is a good tutorial: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/