# 400 Bad request when trying to contact WCF service using XHR

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a WCF web service that will return a json object, but I keep getting a 400 bad request error when I try to make an AJAX call:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:55658/WebServiceWrapper.svc/GetData?_=1318567254842&value=97            HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:55658
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2011 04:40:55 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close
```

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json',
  url: 'http://localhost:55658/WebServiceWrapper.svc/GetData',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    value: 97
  },
  success: function (data) {
    alert('success' + data);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('failure' + errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Here is my WCF service definition:

```
public class WebServiceWrapper : IWebServiceWrapper
{
    public object GetData(int value)
    {
        return new 
        {
            ReturnValue = string.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
        };
    }
}
```

And it's interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWebServiceWrapper
{
    [OperationContract]
    object GetData(int value);
}
```

I know I've solved this problem before, but I can't remember what I had done before. Any help would be greatly appreciated as the hole I'm putting in the wall is just getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: Are you sure of the port number you use in the ajax call (55658)? The origin is reported as 3000.

Answer (score 1):

There a couple of things you may need to do (or check if you have done):

Your GetData OperationContract needs to be decorated with [WebGet] attribute.

```
    [WebGet]
    [OperationContract]
    object GetData(int value);
```

Your WebServiceWrapper class needs to be decorated with [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements] attribute (Add a reference to System.ServiceModel.Web for this to be available)

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class WebServiceWrapper : IWebServiceWrapper
```

The return value from GetData operation will need to be wrapped. An easy way is to use a JavaScriptSerializer to serialize the object to json

```
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(new
                                {
                                    ReturnValue = string.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
                                });
```

You need to make sure you are using a [webHttpBinding] in your endpoints (client and services)

```
<endpoint ... binding="webHttpBinding" ... />
```

I dont know if this next thing is mandatory, but you may need an endpoint behaviour that enables web script

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="[endpointBehaviorName]">
        <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

You will obviously need to refer to this behavior configuration in your endpoint(s)

```
<endpoint ... behaviorConfiguration="[endpointBehaviorName]" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your request you are making an OPTIONS request rather than a GET, which I think jQuery does automatically if you try to do a cross-site XHR request, see this question:

[Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/jquery-why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-insted-of-a-get-request)

I'm not even sure that your server supports the OPTIONS method, hence your 400 error.

Even different port numbers are considered cross-site requests, so you'd better make a proxy page on the actual web site that makes the HTTP request to your WCF Service.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be violating the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You cannot send cross domain AJAX requests. Your application is hosted on `http://localhost:3000` and you are trying to send an AJAX request to `http://localhost:55658`. That's impossible. You can send AJAX requests only to `http://localhost:3000`. You could use [JSONP](http://jasonkelly.net/2009/05/using-jquery-jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax-with-wcf-services/) to circumvent this restriction. And here's [another article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834511.aspx) on MSDN.