# XMLHttpRequest changes POST to OPTION

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

i have this code:

```
net.requestXHR = function() {
    this.xhr = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest === undefined) {
        window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
            try {
                // Use the latest version of the activex object if available
                this.xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
            }
            catch(e1) {
                try {
                    // Otherwise fall back on an older version
                    this.xhr = new ActiveXObject("Mxsml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
                }
                catch(e2) {
                    //Otherwise, throw an error
                    this.xhr = new Error("Ajax not supported in your browser");
                }
            }
        };
    }
    else
        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
net.requestXHR.prototype.post = function(url, data) {
    if(this.xhr != null) {
        this.xhr.open("POST", url);
        this.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        this.xhr.send(data);
    }
}

    var rs = new net.requestSpeech();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(interaction));
    rs.post("http://localhost:8111", JSON.stringify(interaction));
```

when the send execute, i have this log:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8111/ [HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed 74ms]
```

And in localhost:8111 i have a reslet serverResource that accept post, it is problem of same origin policy? i have modify the restlet to put the allow-origin header and i test it with another GET http request (in jquery) and work ok. I have the problem of same origin resolve because i use an html5 browser and my server put the headers in the response, so why the send shows me this error? why change POST for OPTION?
Thanks!

> Possible duplicate?: I think no, but it's true, the problem is the
>   same for both questions, but mine are refers since the question that
>   there is an issue with the browser, and the other, first points to
>   jquery. By experience the time does not count for duplicate, the
>   answers are different but it's true that both questions complement
>   each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256593/why-am-i-getting-an-options-request-instead-of-a-get-request)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yes, this is a "problem with same-origin policy". You are making your request either to a different server or to a different port, meaning that it is a cross-site HTTP request. Here is what [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#functional_overview) has to say about such requests:

> Additionally, for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on
> server's data (in particular, for HTTP methods other than `GET`, or for
> `POST` usage with certain MIME types), the specification mandates that
> browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from
> the server with an HTTP `OPTIONS` request method, and then, upon
> "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual
> HTTP request method.

There is a more detailed description in the [CORS standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol). Your server needs to allow the `OPTIONS` request and send a response with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers allowing the request. Then the browser will make the actual `POST` request.

Comment: What can I do in the case when I can not modify the server's behaviour? I can not access it's source code

Comment: @gbaor: You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which has no same-origin restrictions or (if the server doesn't support that either) you can run a server-side script on your own server that will request the data from the other server and return it - then your JavaScript code can get this data from your server which is same origin.

Answer (score 10):

I was having this exact problem from a JavaScript code that sent an ajax content.

In order to allow the Cross-Origin Request with Preflight I had to do this in the .ASPX that was receiving the petition:

```
//Check the petition Method
if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    //In case of an OPTIONS, we allow the access to the origin of the petition
    string vlsOrigin = Request.Headers["ORIGIN"];
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", vlsOrigin);
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, content-type");
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
}
```

You have to be careful and check what headers are being asked by your petition. I checked those using Fiddler.

Hope this serves someone in the future.

Answer (score 6):

**Answer:**

Your browser is initiating a [PreFlight OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) request.

**Why:**
Because your request is not a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests).

**Why it is not a simple request:** 
Because of "Content-Type" = "application/json".

**Solution:**
Try to use either of below content types :

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, this is a CORS thing.

This is how to handle it in NGINX (based on  [this source](http://blog.rogeriopvl.com/archives/nginx-and-the-http-options-method/)):

```
location / {
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
        add_header Content-Length 0;
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200;
    }
}
```

If you want to allow CORS requests from any origin, replace,

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com";
```

with

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
```

If you don't use authorization, you won't need this bit:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
```

---

For the API I'm developing I needed to whitelist 3 request methods: GET, POST and OPTIONS, and an `X-App-Id` header, so this us what I ended up doing:

```
if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-App-Id";
    add_header Content-Length 0;
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200;
}
```