# How do i post form data as JSON format

Tags: java, json, rest

Posting argument data from my form works perfectly but i need to post the same information using JSON. How can this be done.
My form looks like this.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://myrestfulservice.com/">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <textarea name="about" rows="3"></textarea>
    <input name="file" type="file">
</form>
```

And my JSON string looks like this.

```
{
"name":"Josh U",
"email":"xxx@gmail.com",
"about":"Get rich programming or die tryna be something else",
"file":"@/home/josh/image.png"
}
```

I have tried  using that JSON string but i get the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 500
at com.ijoshluisaac.restful.client.RESTFulClientPostUsingJavaHTTPClientLibrary.main(RESTFulClientPostUsingJavaHTTPClientLibrary.java:35)
```

My JAVA codes looks like this

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

  public class RESTFulClientPostUsingJavaHTTPClientLibrary {

// JSON content to post
private static final String JSON_OBJECT = "{\"name\":\"Josh U\",\"email\":\"xxx@gmail.com\",\"about\":\"Get rich programming or die tryna be something else\",\"file\":\"/home/josh/image.png\"}";

//Web services URLs
private static final String URL_SR = "http://myrestfulservice.com/";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(URL_SR);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(JSON_OBJECT.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Successfully Executed RESTFul POST .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: I think this will help you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481382/how-to-send-form-field-value-to-a-rest-service-using-json-or-ajax)

Comment: Why are you posting JSON to the server when it clearly expects url encoded form data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do 2 steps:

1. First is to convert your form contents into JS object(hard step).
2. Second convert your JS object into JSON format(easy step).

You just need to add more functionality to [jQuery serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to give us our required JS object:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Then use `JSON.stringify` function to convert the JS object into JSON format. You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery/1186309#1186309)

Answer (score -1):

Go for jquery (as it provides many out of box features like serilaize the form parametrs to json)and use below code

```
var frm = $(document.myform);
var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());

 or

var data = $('#yourForm).serializeArray();
```

see http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

```
var url = 'YourURL';

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data ,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {

  }
 });
```

Comment: jQuery serilaize does not make a JSON string!