# OPTIONS Request instead of PUT in XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, rest, web.py

I trying to do the html+javascript part of a web service in REST. With this code as example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"
<script type="text/javascript">
  function testPut( url ){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open( 'PUT', url, false );
  xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'text/plain' );
  xhr.send( null );
  }
</script>
<body>
<form name="test" action="">
    <input type="button" value="Lanceur" onclick="testPut('http://fake.es:8080')" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But in the web server (done with web.py) I getting OPTIONS instead of PUT:

```
111.111.111.111:52014 - - [15/May/2013 17:01:47] "HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS /" - 200 OK
```

How con I solve it? To remove the OPTIONS request and only send a PUT?

Comment: Similar question (here)[http://stackoverflow.com/q/8153832/57091].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My guess is your a re making a cross domain request so the browser is sending the OPTIONS request as a 'preflight-request' asking the server for permission to send the PUT request.

To confirm this is the case, look at the headers of the OPTIONS request. You should see these headers:

- **Origin**: This indicates the domain your client code is
- **Access-Control-Request-Method**: What method you are trying to send
- **Access-Control-Request-Headers**: This header will be included if your request includes headers other than Accept, Content-Type, and a couple other that are accepted by default

```
OPTIONS /cors HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://your_request_domain.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: ...
Host: server_request_domain.com
...
```

If the server gives permission, you should see these header on the OPTIONS response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <<your domain or *>>
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: <<list of allowed headers>>
```

See [this HTML 5 Rocks Tutorial on CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-types-of-cors-requests) for a nice explanation of how Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was developing in two computers, when I tested with the same localhost it works.

Comment: Right, and it may also occur if you "launch" an html file directly from the file system, thus starting the browser on it. The machine is the same, but the localhost server will see it as a CORS. The html must be server by the server itself, instead, to be considered "same origin".