# Error 415 when posting to ASP.Net Core WebAPI using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript, asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest

Working on a new project using a WebAPI backend server and I am having trouble posting to the controller from an actual website, despite Postman having no issues posting to the controller. I get the an error 415, the browser console logging:

```
HTTP415: UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE - The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
(XHR)OPTIONS - http://localhost:5000/api/Users
```

Whilst the log from Kestrel is

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/api/Users  0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/api/Users  0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult[1]
      Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 415
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult:Information: Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 415
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action SchoolsChat.Controllers.UserContoller.Post (SchoolsChat) in 2.5323ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action SchoolsChat.Controllers.UserContoller.Post (SchoolsChat) in 2.5323ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 6.6615ms 415 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 6.6615ms 415
```

I am trying to post the following JSON:

```
{
    UserDOB: "2016-12-18",
    UserFirstName: "asdf",
    UserLastName: "asasdf",
    UserName: "asdf",
    UserSecret: "asdf"
}
```

using this TypeScript class

```
/**
 * JsonPost
 */
class JsonPost {
    private _response: number;
    public get Reponse(): number {
        return this._response;
    }
    constructor(link: string, data: Object) {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.withCredentials = true;

        request.open("POST", APIUri + link, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.onreadystatechange = () => this._response = request.status;
        console.log(request);
        request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}
```

The model of User is

```
public class User
    {
        [KeyAttribute]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [RequiredAttribute]
        public int SchoolId { get; set; }
        [RequiredAttribute]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [RequiredAttribute]
        [DataTypeAttribute(DataType.Password)]
        public string UserSecret { get; set; } // Unnecessary due to school linking?
        [RequiredAttribute]
        public virtual School UserSchool { get; set; }
    }
```

Whilst the controller for posting is simple, just outputting the first name

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]User user)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(user.UserName);
        return StatusCode(200);
    }
```

**Edit**
Whilst the answer from nemec was helpeful in resolving the problem, I found that for the WebAPI specifically the best resolution was to only configure cors using app.UseCors as services.AddCors in many cases didn't actually include the necessary headers in the response.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153832/xmlhttprequest-changes-post-to-option for why you are seeing the `OPTIONS` request instead of a `POST`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Evan mentioned in his comment, your `POST` is turning into an `OPTIONS` when you make a cross-origin ajax request. Due to browsers' cross-origin security policies, your web api needs to tell the browser/js that your website is allowed to make ajax requests against it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

> To setup CORS for your application add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` package to your project.
>
> Add the CORS services in Startup.cs:
>
> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>     services.AddCors();
> }
> ```

If you follow the linked instructions, you can even use `IApplicationBuilder.UseCors` to further customize which sites are allowed.

For example:

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
    builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com")
           .AllowAnyHeader()
);
```

Postman is an app and therefore has the ability to exempt itself from cross-origin rules.

Answer (score 61):

In my case the problem was that I put a `FromBody` attribute before my action parameter.

From:

```
[HttpPost("Contact")]
public async Task<IActionResult> NewContact([FromBody]Contact contact)
```

To:

```
[HttpPost("Contact")]
public async Task<IActionResult> NewContact(Contact contact)
```

Comment: It fixed the issue for me as well but on closer inspection my web app was posting using a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Once I changed the content type of the `POST` to `application/json` `[FromBody]` was able to do it's thing. I've not dug into whether it's possible to use `[FromBody]` in conjunction with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` yet.

Comment: The problem occurs because the ContentType of the [FromBody] must be Json. If its not JSON it will do a 415 error.
When you take out it, it accept allot of ContentType, and no ContentType.

Comment: I agree with @mohas. For me, common cause of 415 errors with ASP.Net Core is a missing binding attribute or a mismatch between the request and the declared binding ([FromBody], [FromForm], [FromQuery] etc). Older versions of MVC could often work OK without binding attributes.

Comment: Had the same error but with a CORS error message on ASP.Net core 3.1. Took me a while to figure this one out since I kept trying cors related fixes.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know why yet, I'm still pretty new to .Net Core Web API's.  I removed the controller attribute [ApiController] and everything fell into place.

In my situation, I have a MVC interface & WebApi on the same project.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

We upgraded to .NET core 3.0 and this required to use [FromQuery] when you're building an object from query parameters, e.g. with a GET request.

Example:

```
[HttpGet("Hierarchy")]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetHierarchy([FromServices] IDeviceHierarchyService service, [FromQuery] HierarchyStructureRequest structureLoad)
```