# The redirect to another page after receiving a json response from a controller to view is not working in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been trying to make an edit password function in ASP.NET Core MVC, the functionality of sending the request from view to the controller is working fine, my issue is when the controller return json to the view, the result is the json response printed in the screen instead of redirect the page to the index if response is success.

Can you please provide an answer or a reference that can help me with this?

I have tried to send `json(Response)` and `json(new {success = true};`.

The controller code is:

```
// GET
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPassword(int? id)
{
    if(id == null || _context.NameEmailTables == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var nameEmailTable = await _context.NameEmailTables.FindAsync(id);

    if (nameEmailTable == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var model = new EditPassword();

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPassword(EditPassword formData)
{
    try
    {
        var UserId = 1;
        var user = await _context.NameEmailTables.FindAsync(UserId);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (user != null && user.Password == formData.OldPassword)
            {
                user.Password = formData.NewPassword;
                _context.Update(user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Old password is incorrect");
            }
        }

        return Json(new {success = false});
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Error in EditPassword action: " + ex.Message);
        return Json(new { success = false });
    }
}
```

And the view markup and code is:

```
@model EditEmail.Models.EditPassword

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EditPassword";
}

<h1>EditPassword</h1>


<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="EditPassword" id="form">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="UserId" />
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OldPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="OldPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="OldPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NewPassword" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NewPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="NewPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                <span id="NewPasswordError" asp-validation-for="NewPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
        const form = document.querySelector("#form");
        btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let formData = {};
            let formElements = form.elements;
            for (let i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
                let element = formElements[i];
                if (element.name) {
                    formData[element.name] = element.value;
                }
            }
         
            fetch("\\NameEmailTables/EditPassword", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData)
            }).then(async response => 
                {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                const res = await response.json();
                if (res.success) {
                    window.location.href = "/NameEmailTables/";
                } else {
                    NewPasswordError.textContent = "The Old Password is wrong";
                
                }).catch(error => console.error("An error occurred:", error)
            );

        })
    }
</script>
```

I also tried:

```
fetch("\\NameEmailTables/EditPassword", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formData)
            }).then(response => 
                {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                return await response.json();}).then(data =>
                if (data.success) {
                    window.location.href = "/NameEmailTables/";
                } else {
                    NewPasswordError.textContent = "The Old Password is wrong";
                
                }).catch(error => console.error("An error occurred:", error)
            );

        })
```

There is no error shown in the network nor the console but the direction to the controller is not working

Comment: `"\\NameEmailTables/EditPassword"` is not a valid URI. URIs only ever contain forward-slashes `/`, not backslashes `\`.

Comment: `return await response.json();}).then(data =>` <-- This line won't work because you're mixing new-style `async/await` with old-style `.then().catch()`. Use one style or the other, not both at the same time. Also, you can't use `await` in a function unless the function has the `async` modifier (yes, this applies to both JS and C#).

Comment: I tried putting it as you said  "/NameEmailTables/EditPassword" and without the async/await, with the same thing, its not redirect to controller

Comment: Have you single-stepped through it with your JS debugger?

Comment: the program return the json response but not entering the second then and for some reason the debugger is not working

Comment: I think you should just rewrite your `fetch` expression using _only_ `async/await` **without** using the old-style `then()`-style of chaining.

Comment: I tried to send an object which is sent to the controller and return a json file but the second then is not working, while if I send a string in the json to the controller it seems not reading the value that I send since it gives me a null as of value
for strange reason if I use ASP.NET MVC without the core the code works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want a mvc controller(without `[ApiController]` attribute) receive json values,you have to add `[FromBody]` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPassword([FromBody]EditPassword formData)
{
}
```

In your case,it would always return   `Json(new {success = false});`

> There is no error shown in the network nor the console but the
> direction to the controller is not working

```
return Json(new { success = false });
```

would retrun an ObjectResult with 200 statue code,won't trigger `catch` method in your codes

Try return objectresult without 200 statue code,such as:

```
return BadRequest(new {success=false});
```

Comment: It didn't work if I add the "[FromBody]" it gives "415 Unsupported Media Type" error

Comment: Since you've set 'Content-Type': 'application/json' in your headers, the error shouldn't occor,would you share a minimal example that could repo?

Comment: I am using database-first approach, Have 3 files: Models (class for database Table, class for editPassword model, class for DBset), Controller for the table, views (create, details, edit, Delete, editpassword) and in the program.cs, I already configure " string connection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Index");
 builder.Services.AddDbContext<NameEmailTableContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));"
is this what you want, I am still learning ASP.NET

Comment: no,it has nothing related with the issue,please check this issue related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208452/error-415-when-posting-to-asp-net-core-webapi-using-xmlhttprequest,just share a minimal example that could reproduce your issue